# WordPress Rewrite Rules for Custom Post Type and Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have found this place to be a good source of information in the past through a lot of Googling for the problems I have run into. My question pertains to the verbose rewrite rules WordPress uses.

I have set up a custom post type called *project*, and I have registered a custom taxonomy called *projects*. Everything works great except for the rewrite slug options as they end up conflicting - most likely due to the rewrite rules.

Basically this is the structure I am looking to achieve:

- `example.com/work/%taxonomy%/%post_name%/` (for posts)
- `example.com/work/%taxonomy%/` (list posts belonging to a particular
  taxonomy term)
- `example.com/work/` (goes to page-work.php which includes taxonomy.php to list all posts associated with that taxonomy)

Here is the code I have so far, but I need help writing the WP_Rewrite rules as this is the bit I am a bit stumped on.

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Projects', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Project', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'project item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
    'new_item' => __('New Project'),
    'view_item' => __('View Project'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Projects'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'work', 'with_front'=>false),
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'query_var' => "project", // This goes to the WP_Query schema
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'comments', 'author', 'excerpt')
);

register_post_type('project' , $args);

// Showcase Taxonomy
register_taxonomy('projects', array('project'), array(
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'label' => 'Project Categories', 
    'singular_label' => 'Project Category',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'work', 'with_front'=>false, 'hierarchical'=>true)
    )
);
```

Many thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: I found a few things to get you started:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite and
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule and
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

Comment: @ChristopherDavis Thanks, I'll look into those a bit more and see how I get on.

Comment: I think this question can be answered by looking at [Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures) If that question does not help you, please edit this question to indicate how it is different.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can solve your problem

```
function my_custom_post_type() {
$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Projects', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Project', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'project item'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
    'new_item' => __('New Project'),
    'view_item' => __('View Project'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Projects'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'Projects' 
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'work', 'with_front'=>false),
    'show_ui' => true,
    '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
    'capability_type' => 'post',
        'query_var' => true, // This goes to the WP_Query schema
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'comments', 'author', 'excerpt')
);

register_post_type( 'work' , $args );

}
function my_custom_taxonomies() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Taxonomy', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Taxonomy', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Taxonomy' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Taxonomy' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Taxonomy' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Taxonomy:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Taxonomy' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Taxonomy' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Taxonomy' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Taxonomy Name' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Taxonomy' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy( 'taxonomy', array('work'), array (
                    'labels' => $labels,
                    'hierarchical' =>false,
                    'show_ui' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'work/taxonomy'),
                    'query_var' => true,
                    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
                    'public' => true,
            ));
}

add_action('init', 'my_custom_post_type', 0);
add_action('init', 'my_custom_taxonomies', 10);
```

what you need to create is archive-work.php (your post type archive)
and taxonomy.php which will use to show your custom taxonomy archive.

Comment: don't forget to change the "taxonomy" for your own taxonomy name. Don't use the same value as your post_type. try to use category for the first try. work/category , register_taxonomy('category, array('work'), array( ......

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a lot of struggling I ended up with this solution.
Just add this to your code

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

---

```
function my_custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Projects', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Project', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'project item'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Project'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Project'),
        'new_item' => __('New Project'),
        'view_item' => __('View Project'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Projects'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Projects' 
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'work', 'with_front'=>false),
        'show_ui' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'capability_type' => 'post',
            'query_var' => true, // This goes to the WP_Query schema
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'comments', 'author', 'excerpt')
    );

    register_post_type( 'work' , $args );

    global $wp_rewrite;   
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();    // this should help 
}
```

Comment: $wp_rewrite->flush_rules() should not be run that often, it should only be run on activation or deactivation hooks or as sparingly as possible. It says so here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules ALSO is pretty much the same function as this one: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules

Comment: On another note, this is how I accomplished it: http://pastebin.com/k7QvxKLi

Comment: @Jared Thanks for pointing, but I couldn't figure out a way to  accompolish this when this is integrated in our theme (ie not via plugin).  Please suggest.

Comment: The code would go in `functions.php` in that case. The code for a plugin and a theme is exactly the same, the only difference is in themes it always goes in `functions.php` or a file included in `functions.php`

Comment: I would suggest using the `after_switch_theme` hook, it's new to 3.3 (IIRC).

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed explanation is [on another post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types), but here's the basic parts you need to add:

1. Register your taxonomies and cpt's as you do.  Make sure your rewrite slug for the taxo is "basename" and the rewrite slug for the cpt is "basename/%tax_name%".
2. Tell wordpress what to do with "%tax_name%" like this:

   ```
   function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
   {
   if ($post->post_type != 'custom_post_type_name')
       return $link;

   if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy_name'))
   {
       $link = str_replace('%taxonomy_name%',array_pop($cats)->term_id, link); // see custom function defined below
   }
   return $link;
   }
   add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
   ```