# Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

Basically I want to achieve a glossary using custom post types and have some issues setting up rewrites the way I want them to be. I want it like that:

The main glossary URL:
`http://example.com/glossary/`

Glossary terms starting with letter **A**:
`http://example.com/glossary/a/`

The URL for a single glossary term:
`http://example.com/glossary/a/atomic/`

I actually achieved this using the code below but I'm sure that it's a very awkward way to do it and I know it's malfunctioning somewhere as the wrong templates are called when viewing the pages. Except for http://example.com/glossary/, where archive-sumo-glossary-term.php gets called as expected, the other two just activate index.php in my theme.

Here goes (`functions.php` in the theme):

```php
add_action('init', 'create_glossary');
function create_glossary()
{
    register_post_type
    (
        'sumo-glossary-term',
        array
        (
            'labels' => array
            (
                'name' => _x('Glossary Terms', 'post type general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Glossary Term', 'post type singular name')
                # And so on …
            ),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array
            (
                'slug' => 'glossary',
                'with_front' => false

            ),
            'query_var' => 'glossary-term',
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );

    register_taxonomy
    (
        'sumo-glossary-letter',
        'sumo-glossary-term',
        array
        (
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array
            (
                'name' => _x('Letters', 'taxonomy general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Letter', 'taxonomy singular name')
                # And so one
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => 'glossary-letter',
            'rewrite' => false
        )
    );
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'glossary_term_permalink', 10, 4);
function glossary_term_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ($post->post_type == 'sumo-glossary-term')
    {
        $permalink = str_replace('glossary/', 'glossary/' . $post->post_name[0] . '/', $post_link);
    }
    return $permalink;
}

add_rewrite_rule('^glossary/([^/]*)?$','index.php?glossary-letter=$matches[1]','top');
add_rewrite_rule('^glossary/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$','index.php?glossary-term=$matches[2]','top');
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can always override the template that will be called with the `template_include` or a related filter, but this might hide deeper problems with custom archives.

As I understand it, you want to use the following structure:

- `/glossary/` should be an archive page for all `sumo-glossary-term` posts
- `/glossary/[letter]/` should be an archive page for posts with the taxonomy term `[letter]` in the `sumo-glossary-letter` taxonomy
- `/glossary/[letter]/[term-name]/` should be an individual `sumo-glossary-term` post

This means that the first will load the template `archive-sumo-glossary-term.php`, the second will load `taxonomy-sumo-glossary-letter.php`, and the third will load `single-sumo-glossary-term.php`.

I achieved this in WordPress 3.2 by explicitly setting the taxonomy rewrite slug, and both the rewrite slug and the archive slug for the post type, and no other rewrite rules. Also, I registered the taxonomy first and the post type after it, to make sure the priorities were right (otherwise a URL like `/glossary/f/page/2` goes to glossary term `page` instead of page 2 of glossary letter `f`).

```
add_action('init', 'create_glossary');
function create_glossary()
{

    register_taxonomy
    (
        'sumo-glossary-letter',
        array(),
        array
        (
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => array
            (
                'name' => _x('Letters', 'taxonomy general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Letter', 'taxonomy singular name')
                # And so one
            ),
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => 'glossary-letter',
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'glossary',
            ),
        )
    );

    register_post_type
    (
        'sumo-glossary-term',
        array
        (
            'labels' => array
            (
                'name' => _x('Glossary Terms', 'post type general name'),
                'singular_name' => _x('Glossary Term', 'post type singular name')
                # And so on …
            ),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array
            (
                'slug' => 'glossary/%sumo-glossary-letter%',
                'with_front' => false

            ),
            'query_var' => 'glossary-term',
            'has_archive' => 'glossary',
            'taxonomies' => array( 'sumo-glossary-letter' ),
        )
    );
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'glossary_term_permalink', 10, 4);
function glossary_term_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%sumo-glossary-letter%' ) ) {
        $glossary_letter = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'sumo-glossary-letter' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%sumo-glossary-letter%', array_pop( $glossary_letter )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow and see if it does the trick and get back here. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, not exactly to tomorrow … It worked, almost perfectly! Thank you!

What is not working is `/glossary/`. Gives me a 404 (`archive-sumo-glossary-term.php` is set up). Any ideas? Have to say that I'm stuck to WP 3.0.1 and it's maybe a version issue. Gotta test it again when I'm able to upgrade.

Anyway, for the most part it's working and for now I don't necessarily need `/glossary/` and just redirect to letter A. Thank you again!

Comment: hey @maryisdead, I had the exact same issue and came up with the exact same solution, but was left with your exact same problem - how do you get /glossary to go to the archive-glossery.php template?
I just found the answer - use `'has_archive' => 'glossary'`, instead of `has_archive => true`

I just noticed Jan has it that way in his answer, but you don't have it that way in your original code - did you update that part?  It started working for me as soon as I made that change

Comment: Hey Jeff! Yes, updated that part. Just checked again, still not working. The WordPress installation in question isn't still up-to-date (3.0.1) so maybe that's still the root of the problem.

Comment: Same problem here, using WP 3.2.1. Still no solution?

Comment: Still relevant code - I'm still using it as my go-to solution to achieve this structure.

One question: if there is a post created that has no taxonomy term assigned to it (so the url would be like customposttypeslug/postslug) - I get a 404 error. Is there a way (probably via permalink rules) to achieve that this will work as well?

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY! The order of the registration of the taxonomy and CPT was the key in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally used this, but what you may want to look at is "add_rewrite_rule"

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

also don't forget to save out permalinks once you've changed them.

Comment: I actually use `add_rewrite_rule`, just scroll my code to the bottom. :-) It's working fine so far, it's only that the wrong templates get called with this way of doing it.