# Custom Post Type Rewrite Throws Headers Sent Errors

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I used [Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures) and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/set-category-to-a-custom-post-type-automatically?replies=10 to create my custom post type. But I am getting some headers already sent errors on my site. Specifically when I go to save a page or try to log in.

Can somebody check the code to make sure it is correct.

```
// PROJECTS
add_action('init', 'create_work_projects');
function create_work_projects() {

    register_taxonomy( 'project_category', array(), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Categories',
            'singular_name' => 'Category'
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'work' )
    ));

    register_post_type( 'projects', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Projects',
            'singular_name' => 'Project'
        ),
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'work/%project_category%',
            //'slug' => 'work',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'has_archive' => 'work',
        'taxonomies' => array( 'project_category' )
    ));
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'work_project_permalink', 10, 4);
function work_project_permalink($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%project_category%' ) ) {
        $glossary_letter = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'project_category' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%project_category%', array_pop( $glossary_letter )->slug, $post_link );
    }
    return $post_link;
}

add_action('publish_projects', 'projects_default_category');
function projects_default_category($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!has_term('', 'project_category', $post_ID)) {
        wp_set_object_terms($post_ID, 'Uncategorized', 'project_category');
    }
}
```

Wordpress 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to a site a friend of mine was working on. Whats weird is that he deleted the problematic file and copied paste the code into a new php file. It seemed to do the trick. worth a shot?