# How to use taxonomy term as permalink folder

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, taxonomy

I've searched around and haven't found a way to do this yet.

I'm trying to create a custom post type that will display a permalink structure that uses the term of a taxonomy as the folder name. Here's an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

### custom taxonomy `page_type`

Example terms:

- article
- video

### custom post type `custom_page`

Example pages:

- carpentry
- quality drywall
- concrete work

### Desired permalink structure

- http://site.com/%page_type%/%custom_page%
- http://site.com/video/quality-drywall

Perhaps this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer by Jan Fabry should help you solve your problem. It had helped me.
[Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures)