# Permalinks for custom post-types within custom taxonomies not found

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have tried to apply the advice offered by TheDeadMedic in [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/14174) to achieve the following URL structure:

example.com/activities = a WP page
example.com/activities/type-term = a custom archive
example.com/activities/type-term/activity-post = a custom post

All URL's work until the lowest one which returns a Wordpress "not found" error.

I don't know whether I need to filter the rewrite rules to make this work. The post I linked above suggests that I have done everything needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks. Here's my code:

```
/*
 * Register custom content objects on initiation
 */
add_action('init', 'register_type'); // Type taxonomy (activities)
add_action('init', 'register_activity'); // Activity post-type
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_activity_link', 10, 2); // Filter permalinks for activity post-type

/*
 * Register Type custom taxonomy for activities
 */
function register_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => ('Types'),
        'singular_name'         => ('Type'),
        'add_new'               => ('Add New Type'),
        'add_new_item'          => ('Add New Type'),
        'edit_item'             => ('Edit Type'),
        'new_item'              => ('New Type'),
        'view_item'             => ('View Type'),
        'search_items'          => ('Search Type'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'activities', 'with_front' => false ),

    );
    register_taxonomy( 'type', 'activity', $args );
}

/*
 * Register Activity custom post-type
 */
function register_activity() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => ('Activities'),
        'singular_name'         => ('Activity'),
        'all_items'             => ('All Activities'),
        'add_new_item'          => ('Add New Activity'),
        'edit_item'             => ('Edit Activity'),
        'new_item'              => ('New Activity'),
        'view_item'             => ('View Activity'),
        'search_items'          => ('Search Activities')
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => false, // Do not appear directly in navigation
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'type', 'revisions', 'comments' ),
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'activities/%tax_type%', 'with_front' => false )
    );

    register_post_type( 'activity', $args );
}

/*
 * Update Type rewrite slug with applicable terms
 */
function filter_activity_link($link, $post) {
    if ($post->post_type != 'activity')
    return $link;

if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type'))
    $link = str_replace('%tax_type%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link);
return $link;
}
```

---

## UPDATE

OK, it turns out you will always need to add rewrite rules to finish this process. The URL's may appear correctly but the database doesn't understand them. [This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures) helped me enormously, along with [this reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) information on regex.

I just needed to add the code

```
add_rewrite_rule('^activities/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' ,'index.php?activity=$matches[2]','top';
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in wordpress to automatically replace `%tax_type%` in the rewrite slug. You'd have to add some custom code to handle it like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723457/wordpress-custom-type-permalink-containing-taxonomy-slug

Comment: Isn't that covered by the post_type_link filter function at the bottom?

Comment: The URL's are definitely working as they should be, it's just the posts aren't being found. I suspect I need to alter the rewrite rules somehow, but not sure how to code this.

Comment: OK I worked this out eventually, with help from [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures). I updated the question with my solution, for anyone else who needs it.