# Custom category URL not displaying posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom post type with custom categories using the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'products',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
            ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'supports' => array('title','editor','comments'),   
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' ),
        )
    );
}

function news_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'products',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Product Categories' ),
            'sort' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products' )
        )
    );      
}
add_action( 'init', 'news_init' );
```

For some reason I just can't display the posts for specific categories. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm trying to goto the url /products/category/monitors for example but it displays a page not found. I've duplicated the archive.php template and renamed it category-monitors.php.

Comment: **custom post type** and **taxonomy** with same slug - `products `? try changing one of them

Comment: @amit Ok thanks, I've changed the taxonomy to `products-category` so would that make the url /products/products-category/monitors? If so that's giving a page not found as well.

Answer (score 1):

First check if `custom post type` + `taxonomy` archive displaying correct posts by visiting a url structure like this -

> mysite.com/?post_type=products&products-category=monitors

If it's working then you can do some custom rewrite rules to show them just like you want.

**Here are some recommended answers on WPSE describing same**

- [Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures?rq=1)
- [Custom post types, taxonomies, and permalinks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks)

Comment: Thanks. It's now loading a page but is displaying ALL the products rather than just the monitors. Is there a way to use a custom template for monitors and another template for other products?