# Changing permalink of custom category

Tags: posts, permalinks

I've tried reading up on past posts here but my head is just spinning.

My problem is I'd like to change my permalink structure for a custom full width posts under a custom category.

For example, my permalink structure for posts is `example.com/04/2013/postname` and for my custom posts I'd like the permalink structure to be `example.com/categoryname/postname`.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a few people create a custom function to filter in custom taxonomy names into `post_type_link`. This post provides a simple approach to problem:

[Mixing custom post type and taxonomy rewrite structures?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures)