# Post not showing in my custom advanced search

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, search

I've created a custom-search-page for my theme that have to search in my CPT non-hierarchical taxonomy and eventually filter the results if some preference is inserted through the options form of custom-fields.

i have and advanced-searchform.php that's just a form

```
    <input type="hidden" name="search" value="advanced">

<input type="text" value="" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Cosa c\'è in frigo?', 'whattodo' ); ?>" name="ing" id="ing" />
```

and three select for this kind of post custom fields.

```
<select name="tempo" id="tempo">
<select name="tempo" id="portata">
<select name="tempo" id="difficolta">
```

All of this run into advanced-search-results.php with the following code,plus   the query loop at the bottom of the page who i didn't include now.

```
 <?php
// Get data from URL into variables
$_ing = $_GET['ing'] != '' ? $pieces = explode(" ", $_GET['ing']) : '';
$_tempo = $_GET['tempo'] != '' ? $_GET['tempo'] : '';
$_portata = $_GET['portata'] != '' ? $_GET['portata'] : '';
$_difficolta = $_GET['difficolta'] != '' ? $_GET['difficolta'] : '';



// VERIFY IF SOMETHING WAS TYPED IN SEARCH
if( ! empty( $pieces ) ){

//BUILDING ARRAY FOR TAX_QUERY RELATIONS
foreach( $pieces as $pezzo ){
                $tag[] = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'ingredienti',
                    'terms' => "'".$pezzo."'",
                    'field' => 'slug');
        };
}

// Start the Query
$v_args = array(
        'post_type'     =>  'ricetta', // your CPT
        'tax_query'           => array(
                            'relation' => 'AND',
                             $tag,
            ),
'meta_query'    =>  array(
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'tempo_di_realizzazione',                                         'value'   => $_tempo,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE', 
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'portata', 
                                    'value'   => $_portata,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',                                     ),array(
                                    'key'     => 'difficolta',                                         'value'   => $_difficolta,
                                    'compare' => 'LIKE',                                     )

                            )
    );
$ricettaSearchQuery = new WP_Query( $v_args );

// Open this line to Debug what's query WP has just run
var_dump($ricettaSearchQuery->request);
```

here is the problem.If i run this kind of tax_query in the index.php page without the custom meta fields,all runs smooth and i obtain the kind of post that i expect to.But if i run this in this form,i achive just nothing found,it's like wordpress can't read the posts taxonomy from this page.

i attach the var_dump() of my query.

```
string(813) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wtdx_posts.ID FROM wtdx_posts INNER JOIN wtdx_postmeta ON ( wtdx_posts.ID = wtdx_postmeta.post_id ) INNER JOIN wtdx_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wtdx_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) INNER JOIN wtdx_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wtdx_posts.ID = mt2.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( 0 = 1 ) ) AND ( ( wtdx_postmeta.meta_key = 'tempo_di_realizzazione' AND CAST(wtdx_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%' ) AND ( mt1.meta_key = 'portata' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%contorno%' ) AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'difficolta' AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE '%%' ) ) AND wtdx_posts.post_type = 'ricetta' AND (wtdx_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wtdx_posts.post_author = 1 AND wtdx_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wtdx_posts.ID ORDER BY wtdx_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10" Nessuna Ricetta Trovata
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found that at this point the taxonomy were not properly linked?Even if i have registered everything well,and i have even tried register_taxonomy_for_object_type.BTW

[Page not found taxonomy custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175712/page-not-found-taxonomy-custom-post-type) here i've found my answer with this loop in functions.php