# Dynamically populate permalinks

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm using a fairly standard permalink structure in wordpress e.g. example.com/custom-name/post-title

However, I wish to prepend the 'custom-post-type' with a location name from my database. So the new permalink will look like this example.com/custom-name-location/post-title where the 'location is dynamically fed from post meta.

I know that I can use 'rewrite' to change the slug part of the permalink, but how do I do it dynamically for each post?

So far I have this in my theme setup.php:

```
$region = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT location_town FROM wp_postmeta");

register_post_type( 'custom-name',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Name' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Name' )
        ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category'),
    'supports' => array('title','author','editor','comments','thumbnail'),
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-name-'.$region.''),
    )
);
```

This works to some extent but the permalink it outputs is example.com/custom-name-Array/post-title

Obviously I need fetch the actual entry for the current post rather than 'Array'. Is there an easy way to do this?

Update: This is where I'm at so far. This creates the custom part of the permalink (which displays correctly at the top of the edit post page. However, when browsing to the page I get a 404 error.

```
function create_post_type() {

register_taxonomy
(
    'surf-school-region',
    array(),
    array
    (
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => array
        (
            'name' => _x('Regions', 'taxonomy general name'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Region', 'taxonomy singular name')
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => 'school-region',
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'region',
        ),
    )
);

register_post_type( 'surf-school',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Surf Schools' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'School' )
        ),
        'supports' => array('title','author','editor','comments','thumbnail'),
        'public' => true,
        'rewrite' => array
        (
            'slug' => 'surf-school-%surf-school-region%',
            'with_front' => false

        ),
        'query_var' => 'surf-school',
        'has_archive' => 'region',
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','category','surf-school-region'),
        'menu_position' => 5
        )
);

add_filter('post_type_link', 'surf_school_permalink', 10, 4);
function surf_school_permalink($post_link, $post)
{
    if ( false !== strpos( $post_link, '%surf-school-region%' ) ) {
        $school_region = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'surf-school-region' );
        $post_link = str_replace( '%surf-school-region%', array_pop( $school_region )->slug, $post_link );
    }

return $post_link;
}
```

Comment: when you register a post type, the rewrite rule is created as a *pattern* that the actual post permalinks match. the part where a value is dynamically inserted into a permalink happens at a different stage, when the permalink for a specific post is actually output, not when the post type is registered. if you search here for `post_type_link`, you'll find a number of questions and answers that might help you.

Comment: Thanks Milo. That has got me almost to where I want to be.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like it doesn't work as well as I had hoped. I used the code from here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/mixing-custom-post-type-and-taxonomy-rewrite-structures which has allowed me to add custom taxonomies to the permalink. However, it generates a 404 error when browsing to the page... even though the permalink in the wp edit post page seems fine?!

Comment: add your current code to your question.

Comment: @Milo I've updated the original question to show where I've got to.