# How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, hierarchical

I've been combing this site and google for the answer and I've come up completely empty.  Basically I want to do exactly what [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks) asks, but I need a hierarchical taxonomy.  The answer given in that post works great, but only with a single level taxonomy.  Is it possible to do what I want?  I've tried a million things, but none work, at best I can get the right permalinks but they come up 404.

To visually illustrate what I want:

```
/basename/ - ideally a page, but I think this will cause a permalink collision    
/basename/top-cat/ - top parent custom taxonomy archive    
/basename/top-cat/child-cat/ - child cat custom taxonomy archive     
/basename/top-cat/child-cat/grandchild-cat/ - grandchild cat custom taxonomy archive    
/basename/top-cat/child-cat/grandchild-cat/post-name/ - my custom post type post
```

You can do this fine with the built in posts and categories, how do you do it with custom taxonomies and custom post types?  I know that you need to use `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tax-name', 'with_front' => true, 'hierarchical' => true ),` to get hierarchical slugs, which works fine on the archive pages, but the custom post type posts come up 404.  If I remove the `'hierarchical' => true` part then the posts work, but I lose the hierarchical urls (only /basename/grandchild-cat/post-name/ works).

So, any solutions?  Thank you so much, this has been driving me nuts for about 3 weeks now.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

After combining a bunch of pieces of other answers I got it working!  So here's the solution for those of you who are struggling with this too:

[This post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5308/custom-post-types-taxonomies-and-permalinks) and [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28979/how-to-change-permalink-structure-for-custom-post-type-and-its-taxonomies) helped me out some, so thanks to those guys.

Note, all this code, plus your initial custom post type and taxonomy registration code goes in your `functions.php` file.

First get your slugs right when defining your custom post types and taxonomies: for the custom post type it should be `basename/%taxonomy_name%` and the slug for your taxonomy should be just `basename`.  Don't forget to also add `'hierarchical' => true` to the taxonomy rewrite array to get nested terms in your url.  Also make sure `query_var` is set to `true` in both cases.

You need to add a new rewrite rule so WordPress knows how to interpret your url structure.  In my case the custom post type part of the uri will always be the 5th uri segment, so I defined my match rule accordingly.  Note that you may have to change this if you use more or less uri segments.  If you'll have varying levels of nested terms then you'll need to write a function to check whether the the last uri segment is a custom post type or a taxonomy term to know which rule to add (ask me if you need help on that).

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules['basename/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?custom_post_type_name=$matches[4]'; // my custom structure will always have the post name as the 5th uri segment
    $newRules['basename/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?taxonomy_name=$matches[1]'; 

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

Then you need to add this code to let workpress how to handle `%taxonomy_name%` in your custom post type rewrite slug structure:

```
function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'custom_post_type_name')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy_name'))
    {
        $link = str_replace('%taxonomy_name%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'taxonomy_name', false, '/', true), $link); // see custom function defined below
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
```

I created a custom function based on Wordpress's own `get_category_parents`:

```
// my own function to do what get_category_parents does for other taxonomies
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {    
    $chain = '';   
    $parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

    if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
        return $parent;
    }

    if ($nicename)    
        $name = $parent -> slug;        
else    
        $name = $parent -> name;

    if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {    
        $visited[] = $parent -> parent;    
        $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

    }

    if ($link) {
        // nothing, can't get this working :(
    } else    
        $chain .= $name . $separator;    
    return $chain;    
}
```

Then you need to flush your permalinks (just load your permalinks settings page).

Now everything 'should' work hopefully!  Go make a bunch of taxonomy terms and nest them correctly, then make some custom post type posts and categorize them correctly.  You can also make a page with the slug `basename`, and everything should work the way I specified in my question.  You may want to create some custom taxonomy archive pages to control how they look and add some kind of [taxonomy widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-widget/) plugin to show your nested categories in the sidebar.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Fixed- see question. Jeff, thanks for your explanation! But might it be possible for you to post the custom posttype / taxonomy build? So i can see what i am doing [wrong](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46994/custom-permalinks-post-type-hierarchical-taxonomys) ? Would be realy thankfull!

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for your answer! I'm almost there, after 4 hours fighting with this. My only problem is that I get a double slash before the post name (as this: portfolio/diseno-grafico-2/logo//alquimia-sonora/ ) Can you help me?

Comment: @Cmorales, Not sure without seeing your code, but look for a place where you manually define a slash before your post name, like maybe the cpt slug registration or in the filter_post_type function?  If you can't track down where you're adding the extra slash then you could just strip the last character from the returned value of the get_taxonomy_parents function called in filter_post_type_link, because that will leave you with a trailing slash, which is the first of the double.  Good luck.

Comment: I created the permalinks like your guide but the default link in wordpress for custom post type:
domain.com/my-post-type/custom-post-type-name
(domain.com/place/lotus-hotel) I just test your code in the function.php, I can't find the way to add custom taxonomy to above link ( domain.com/place/tokyo/lotus-hotel) - tokyo is my custom taxonomy

Comment: Many many many thanks for this.  One minor issue though, it seems to polute the rewrite rules with a bunch of %taxonomy_name% entries or in my case: `apps/%primary_tag%/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?%primary_tag%$matches[1]&apps-post=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]`  The rules I add manually take precedence and seem to do the job, but these entries imply something isn't quite right.  Any ideas?

Comment: "If you'll have varying levels of nested terms then you'll need to write a function to check whether the the last uri segment is a custom post type or a taxonomy term to know which rule to add (ask me if you need help on that)..." Well, can you help me, please? :)

Comment: ^ that's exactly what i needed. anybody know how to do it? see my question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102246/wordpress-returns-404-on-custom-rewrite-rules

Comment: This worked good, but for some reason it's only pulling the parent category and none of the children. I copied exactly as you posted and only changed my post type and tax names where indicated. Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is a little old, but do you have any ideas on how to keep '/basename' pointed towards the most recent items in that post type regardless of taxonomy?

Comment: After 3 hours of googling, this is the answer. For those of you who are using a /post_type/term/slug/ format (without hierarchy), you can remove the get_taxonomy_parents() function and substitute it with $cats[0]->slug since there's already a check for if it has terms. That function is also the thing that adds another slash.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at <strike>[this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hierarchical-urls/)</strike> ([now on github](https://github.com/vmassuchetto/wp-hierarchical-urls)). It provides hierarchical URLs for categories, but you can easily adapt to any taxonomy.

The rule creation follows a [recursive function](https://github.com/vmassuchetto/wp-hierarchical-urls).

Comment: This plugin no longer is available.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with varying level of nesting,

```
/basename/top-cat/ -> Top Cat Archive
/basename/top-cat/post-name/ -> Post in Top Cat
/basename/top-cat/child-cat/ -> Child Cat Archive
/basename/top-cat/child-cat/post-name/ -> Post in Child Cat
```

I ended up using Jeff's solution without the `rewrite_rules_array` filter. Instead I used the `request` filter to check if the last url part is a valid postname and add it to the query_vars.

eg.

```
function vk_query_vars($qvars){
    if(is_admin()) return $qvars;
    $custom_taxonomy = 'product_category';
    if(array_key_exists($custom_taxonomy, $qvars)){
        $custom_post_type = 'product';


        $pathParts = explode('/', $qvars[$custom_taxonomy]);
        $numParts = sizeof($pathParts);

        $lastPart = array_pop($pathParts);
        $post = get_page_by_path($lastPart, OBJECT, $custom_post_type);
        if( $post && !is_wp_error($post) ){
            $qvars['p'] = $post->ID;
            $qvars['post_type'] = $custom_post_type;
        }
    }
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter('request', 'vk_query_vars');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on Jeff's solution. The `rewrite_rules_array` may not be needed depending on what your application is. This simplifies the `filter_post_type_link` and does not require any additional functions. It uses the built-in [get_term_parents_list()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_parents_list/)

```php
function PLUGIN_filter_post_type_link($post_link, $post)
{
    $postTypes = ['CUSTOM-POST-TYPE'];
    $taxonomy = 'taxonomy';
    if (in_array($post->post_type, $postTypes, $strict=true)) {
        if ($terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy)
        ) {
            $args = [
                'format' => 'slug',
                'separator' => '/',
                'link' => false,
                'inclusive' => true,
            ];

            return str_replace(
                "%{$taxonomy}%",
                rtrim(
                    get_term_parents_list($terms[0]->term_id, $taxonomy, $args),
                    "/"
                ),
                $post_link);
        }
        return str_replace("%{$taxonomy}%", '', $post_link);
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```