# Custom permalink with child taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, url-rewriting

This may ressemble other questions, but i'm posting my own as I couldn't find a conclusive answer that worked for me.

**What you need to know**

I have a custom post type (products), with a custom taxonomy (collections). My collections taxonomy is hierarchical. For example, I have a parent collection (bathroom) which will have a good number of sub collections.

**What i'm trying to do**

I'm trying to obtain permalinks for my products which include both the parent collection and the child collection, example

```
 http://<domain>/products/bathroom/collection-1/postname
```

**What i've tried**

Basically i've been playing around with the rewrite parameter when registering my CPT and Taxonomy, as well as the 'post_type_link' hook.

I've managed to get it working *partially*, that is, by displaying only the parent collection in the permalink.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Also, my permalink structure is : /%category%/%postname%/

**Some of my code**

*Registering CPT / Taxonomy*

```
 register_taxonomy( 'collection', array(  ), array(
      'label' => 'collections',
      'public' => TRUE,
      'show_ui' => TRUE,
      'hierarchical' => TRUE,
      'query_var' => 'collections',
      'rewrite' => TRUE
 ));

 register_post_type( 'product', array(
      'label' => 'products',
      'public' => TRUE,
      'publicly_queryable' => TRUE,
      'show_ui' => TRUE,
      'show_in_menu' => TRUE,
      'taxonomies' => array( 'collection' ),
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'custom-fields' ),
      'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'products/%collection%', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true )
 ));

flush_rewrite_rules();
```

*post type link hook*

```
 if( strpos( $permalink, '%collection%' ) === FALSE )
      return $permalink;

 $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'collection' );
 $tax_slug = "";

 if( empty( $terms[0]->parent ) )
 {
      $tax_slug = $terms[0]->slug;// . "/" . $terms[1]-> slug;
      //Second part 404's my permalinks, so commented out
 }
 else
 {
      $tax_slug = $terms[1]->slug;// . "/" . $terms[0]-> slug;
      //Second part 404's my permalinks, so commented out
 }

 $permalink = str_replace( '%collection%', $tax_slug, $permalink );

 return $permalink;
```

Comment: Just a note: You shouldn't use `flush_rewrite_rules()` on the `init` hook _ever_. Read here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Flushing_Rewrite_on_Activation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer your question! I just had the same exact issue myself and figured it out today, so I know exactly what you need to do.

I give [very detailed instructions and code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types/39862#39862) on my own question posting, so go look there and see if it solves the issue for you.  Let me know how it goes or if you have more questions.

Comment: Just to quickly give you a preview of the full answer, your missing the wordpress rewrite rule and you'll need to do some extra work in your filter to get the hierarchical categories.

Comment: Looking into it now, i'll comment back if I have questions, thanks.

Comment: I didn't need to add any rewrite rules, but your solution helped get my permalinks working, thank you.

Comment: Awesome.  Interesting you didn't need the rewrite rules... I wonder if they are necessary for my case or not.