# Custom permalinks - post type - hierarchical taxonomy's

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, hierarchical

I did folowed the [steps / solution from Jeff](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) it helped me alot with he's settings, got it for about 90% working properly. But getting stuck on the post / postname. It loads now the producten/%taxonomy_products%/ without the 404 errors. But when i click further on a post i get the 404 errors again.

Maybe you can see what i'am doing wrong?

**Custom post type and taxonomy settings 'Sorry for the dutch words' :**

```
    add_action( 'init', 'products_taxonomy_options' );
function products_taxonomy_options() {

//=============== Register custom post type - PRODUCTS ================

register_post_type('products',
  array( 'label'                    => __('Producten'), // Postype
         'labels'                   => array( 'name'                => __('Producten'),
                                              'singular_name'       => __('Producten'),
                                              'add_new'             => __('Product toevoegen'),
                                              'add_new_item'        => __('Nieuw product'),
                                              'edit_item'           => __('Wijzig product'),
                                              'new_item'            => __('Nieuw product'),
                                              'all_items'           => __('Alle producten'),
                                              'view_item'           => __('Bekijk producten'),
                                              'search_items'        => __('Zoek producten'),
                                              'not_found'           => __('Er zijn geen producten gevonden'),
                                              'not_found_in_trash'  => __('Geen producten gevonden in de prullenbak')                                   
                                    ),
          'public'                  => true,
          'can_export'              => true,
          'show_ui'                 => true,    // UI in admin panel
          '_builtin'                => false,   // It's a custom post type, not built in
          '_edit_link'              => 'post.php?post=%d',
          'capability_type'         => 'post',
          //'menu_icon'             => get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/favicon.ico',
          'hierarchical'            => true,
          'rewrite'                 => array(   "slug" => "producten"), // Permalinks
          'supports'                => array(   'title',
                                                'editor',                                                                                               
                                                'thumbnail',
                                    ),               
          'show_in_menu'            => true,
          'taxonomies'              => array('productcat')
        )
    );


//=============== Register custom taxonomy - PRODUCTS CATEGORY ================ 

register_taxonomy(  "productcat", 
                array(  "products"  ), 
                array ( "hierarchical"      => true, 
                        "label"             => "Product categorieën", 
                        'labels'            => array(   'name'              => __('Product categorieën'),
                                                        'singular_name'     => __('Product categorie'),
                                                        'search_items'      => __('Categorieën zoeken'),
                                                        'popular_items'     => __('Populaire categorieën'),
                                                        'all_items'         => __('Alle categorieën'),
                                                        'parent_item'       => __('Huidige categorie'),
                                                        'parent_item_colon' => __('Huidige categorie:'),
                                                        'edit_item'         => __('Wijzig categorie'),
                                                        'update_item'       => __('Update categorie'),
                                                        'add_new_item'      => __('Nieuwe categorie toevoegen'),
                                                        'new_item_name'     => __('Nieuwe categorie')
                                            ), 
                          'show_ui'         => false,
                          'query_var'       => true,
                          '_builtin'        => false,
                          'paged'           => true,
                          'rewrite'         => array(   'hierarchical'      => true, 
                                                        'slug'              =>'products',
                                                        'with_front'        => false
                                            ),
                        )
                );

}
```

**Jeff's settings:**

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules['producten/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?products=$matches[4]'; // my custom structure will also have the post name as the 5th uri segment
    $newRules['producten/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?productcat=$matches[1]'; 

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'products')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'productcat'))
    {
        $link = str_replace('%taxonomy_products%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'productcat', false, '/', true), $link); // see custom function defined below
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);

// my own function to do what get_category_parents does for other taxonomies
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {    
    $chain = '';   
    $parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

    if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
        return $parent;
    }

    if ($nicename)    
        $name = $parent -> slug;        
else    
        $name = $parent -> name;

    if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {    
        $visited[] = $parent -> parent;    
        $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

    }

    if ($link) {
        // nothing, can't get this working :(
    } else    
        $chain .= $name . $separator;    
    return $chain;    
}
```

**Permalink settings:**

```
/producten/%taxonomy_products%/%postname%/
```

[Working with the Taxonomic SEO Permalink plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomic-seo-permalinks/)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you flush your rules?

Comment: I dont realy know how i can flush the permalinks, because it needs to be done on theme activation? Or can i also just put it in the taxonomy build up? I tried it on this way [link](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/manually-clear-wordpress-rewrite-rules-mysql-phpmyadmin/) but the fields are empty or not visible in the database.

Comment: Just save your permalink settings once.

Comment: Yes, i tried that also first with different settings, then tried it with the standard permalinks. When that is active i didnt get any errors and worked nice. But when i want to change back to the seo friendly permalinks structure i'm getting again the 404 error result but only on the post pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for referencing my solution.  You forgot one part though - defining the rewrite of your cpt.  From my solution:

> First get your slugs right when defining your custom post types and
>   taxonomies: for the custom post type it should be
>   `basename/%taxonomy_name%` and the slug for your taxonomy should be
>   just basename. Dont forget to also add 'hierarchical' => true to the
>   taxonomy rewrite array to get nested terms in your url. Also make sure
>   query_var is set to true in both cases.

So in your case your rewrite for your custom post type should be `producten/%productcat%`.  Also it looks like in my `filter_post_type_link` function you need to change `%taxonomy_products%` to `%productcat%`.

Hopefully that will make it work!

Comment: Thanks changed that, but also didnt mentioned in the newRules he did skipped step 2.

`$newRules['producten/(.+)/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?products=$matches[2]';
$newRules['producten/(.+)/?$']                   = 'index.php?productcat=$matches[1]';`