# Remove slug in URL custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I created two custom post type and taxonomys.
For created permalinks I have been following the steps from the [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types/39862#39862) with [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75172/126472) double slash fix. It's for first custom type.

I  dublicated functions for second custom type, but for this type I need save this structure, but without slug in taxonomy and post URLs.

Now

> domen/type-slug/category/category
>   domen/type-slug/category/category/posname

I need

> domen/category/category
>   domen/category/category/posname

How can do that?

WP 4.8.1