# Help with hierarchical custom taxonomies and permalinks...almost there

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I'm trying to get permalinks working with custom taxonomies and custom post types.  Following the instructions [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39862/9253) I was able to get it *almost* working, but one small glitch.

The code to register the taxonomy looks like this:

```
$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products', 'hierarchical' => true, 'with_front' => true),
    // 'rewrite' => true,
    'query_var' => true
);

register_taxonomy( 'tc_product_type', array('tc_products'), $args );
```

The code to register the post type:

```
$post_type_args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'singular_label'    => __('Product'),
    'public'            => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'publicly_queryable'=> true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'capability_type'   => 'post',
    'has_archive'       => true,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'products/%taxonomy_name%/'),
    // 'rewrite'            => array('slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false),
    'supports'          => $supports,
    'menu_position'     => 0,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
 );


register_post_type('tc_products',$post_type_args);
```

The permalinks themselves are created perfectly, and viewing the taxonomy pages works perfectly, but when viewing the post on the site, I get a 404.  I dumped the WP_Query and it looks like it's using the last segment of the permalink URI as the tc_product_type, instead of the post slug (in the case the post slug is '77777-2'):

```
    WP_Query::__set_state(array(
   'query_vars' => 
  array (
    'tc_product_type' => '77777-2',
    'error' => '',
    'm' => 0,
    'p' => 0,
    'post_parent' => '',
    'subpost' => '',
    'subpost_id' => '',
    'attachment' => '',
    'attachment_id' => 0,
    'name' => '',
    'static' => '',
    'pagename' => '',
    'page_id' => 0,
    'second' => '',
    'minute' => '',
    'hour' => '',
    'day' => 0,
    'monthnum' => 0,
    'year' => 0,
    'w' => 0,
    'category_name' => '',
    'tag' => '',
    'cat' => '',
    'tag_id' => '',
    'author_name' => '',
    'feed' => '',
    'tb' => '',
    'paged' => 0,
    'comments_popup' => '',
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'preview' => '',
    's' => '',
    'sentence' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'category__in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'category__not_in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'category__and' => 
    array (
    ),
    'post__in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'post__not_in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'tag__in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'tag__not_in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'tag__and' => 
    array (
    ),
    'tag_slug__in' => 
    array (
    ),
    'tag_slug__and' => 
    array (
    ),
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => false,
    'suppress_filters' => false,
    'cache_results' => true,
    'update_post_term_cache' => true,
    'update_post_meta_cache' => true,
    'post_type' => '',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'nopaging' => false,
    'comments_per_page' => '50',
    'no_found_rows' => false,
    'taxonomy' => 'tc_product_type',
    'term' => '77777-2',
    'order' => 'DESC',
  ),
   'tax_query' => 
  WP_Tax_Query::__set_state(array(
     'queries' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'taxonomy' => 'tc_product_type',
        'terms' => 
        array (
          0 => '77777-2',
        ),
        'include_children' => true,
        'field' => 'slug',
        'operator' => 'IN',
      ),
    ),
     'relation' => 'AND',
  )),
   'meta_query' => 
  WP_Meta_Query::__set_state(array(
     'queries' => 
    array (
    ),
     'relation' => NULL,
  )),
   'post_count' => 0,
   'current_post' => -1,
   'in_the_loop' => false,
   'comment_count' => 0,
   'current_comment' => -1,
   'found_posts' => '0',
   'max_num_pages' => 0,
   'max_num_comment_pages' => 0,
   'is_single' => false,
   'is_preview' => false,
   'is_page' => false,
   'is_archive' => false,
   'is_date' => false,
   'is_year' => false,
   'is_month' => false,
   'is_day' => false,
   'is_time' => false,
   'is_author' => false,
   'is_category' => false,
   'is_tag' => false,
   'is_tax' => false,
   'is_search' => false,
   'is_feed' => false,
   'is_comment_feed' => false,
   'is_trackback' => false,
   'is_home' => false,
   'is_404' => true,
   'is_comments_popup' => false,
   'is_paged' => false,
   'is_admin' => false,
   'is_attachment' => false,
   'is_singular' => false,
   'is_robots' => false,
   'is_posts_page' => false,
   'is_post_type_archive' => false,
   'query_vars_hash' => 'e63e67c24b4fac79b23b43e0704197c3',
   'query_vars_changed' => false,
   'thumbnails_cached' => false,
   'query' => 
  array (
    'tc_product_type' => 'cotton-candy/tasty-tubs-2/77777-2',
  ),
   'request' => ' SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  tc_posts.* FROM tc_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND 0 = 1 AND tc_posts.post_type IN (\'post\', \'page\', \'attachment\', \'tc_testamonials\', \'tc_press\', \'tc_products\', \'tc_service\', \'tc_variant_group\', \'tc_variation_item\', \'tc_variation_rule\', \'tc_coupon\', \'tc_payment\', \'tc_order\', \'tc_contact\', \'tc_contact_address\', \'tc_project\', \'tc_activity\') AND (tc_posts.post_status = \'publish\' OR tc_posts.post_status = \'private\') GROUP BY tc_posts.ID ORDER BY tc_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10',
   'posts' => 
  array (
  ),
   'queried_object' => NULL,
   'queried_object_id' => 0,
))
```

Am I missing something somewhere?  How do I tell WP that the last segment is the page slug?

Edit:  forgot something important.  In the post linked to above, he creates the rewrite rules knowing that the page slug will always be at a particular segment in the permalink.  This won't work in my case, as there will be posts under each taxonomy...meaning I won't know the exact position of the slug (except that it will be the end, of course).  Is there a rewrite rule that would cover that scenario?  How would it know whether the last segment is a taxonomy or post slug?

Edit 2:  Adding a dump of the related rewrite rules:

```
array (
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=tc_products&paged=$matches[1]',

/*...more rules, then...*/

 'products/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?tc_product_type=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
 'products/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?tc_product_type=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
 'products/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?tc_product_type=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
 'products/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?tc_product_type=$matches[1]',

/*...more rules, then...*/


 'products/%taxonomy_name%/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(.+?)/trackback/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&tc_products=$matches[2]&tb=1',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&tc_products=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&tc_products=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&tc_products=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&tc_products=$matches[2]&cpage=$matches[3]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&tc_products=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
 'products/%taxonomy_name%/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$' => 'index.php?%taxonomy_name%$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]',
/*...more rules...*/
)
```

It looks like it's matching this rule:

```
 'products/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?tc_product_type=$matches[1]',
```

Not sure how to make it match the others, or if the others are even valid rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get it working by hooking into the 'request' filter, then checking to see if the last segment is term or not.  If it's not, change the $request var:

```
function alter_the_query( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new WP_Query();  // the query isn't run if we don't pass any query vars
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( !$dummy_query->is_admin && isset($request['tc_product_type']) ){       
        $lastSegment = basename($request['tc_product_type']);
        if(get_term_by('slug',$lastSegment,  'tc_product_type') === FALSE){
            $request['post_type'] = 'tc_products';
            $request['tc_products'] = $lastSegment;
            $request['name'] = $lastSegment;
        }
    }

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'alter_the_query' );
```