# Safe to throw 404 error in request filter?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, 404-error, request-filter

I am working on a plug-in for my personal site and I would like it have a certain permalink structure (/projects/project-type/sub-type/project). To achieve this, I am using the [`request`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request) filter.

Inside my hook method, I am checking to make sure that the taxonom(y|ies) (project_type) exists before I load the post type (project). If it does not, the filter throws a 404 error and loads the theme's error template instead of just showing the project. Is it safe to do this?

```
public function request( $request ) {
    $dummy_query = new \WP_Query();
    $dummy_query->parse_query( $request );

    if ( ! $dummy_query->is_admin && isset( $request['project_type'] ) ) {
        $last_segment = basename( $request['project_type'] );

        if ( false === get_term_by( 'slug', $last_segment, 'project_type' ) ) {
            $types = explode( '/', substr( $request['project_type'], 0, strrpos( $request['project_type'], '/' ) ) );

            foreach( $types as $type ) {
                if ( false === get_term_by( 'slug', $type, 'project_type' ) ) {
                    header( 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found' );
                    locate_template( array( '404.php' ), true, true );
                    exit;
                }
            }

            $request['post_type'] = 'project';
            $request['project'] = $last_segment;
            $request['name'] = $last_segment;
        }
    }

    return $request;
}
```

This code was modified from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51171/8554).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't see particular problem with this, you do kind of break out of code flow at early point.

I would try to go for setting query to `is_404` instead and let it reach template processing and 404 in template hierarchy naturally.

Comment: Thanks, Rarst. Something like this: `$query = new WP_Query(); $query->is_404 = true;`?

Comment: @Joseph not quite, you need to set in main `$wp_query` object but I don't think `request` filter gives access to it, so different hook or global var.

Comment: Looking through the source, it seems that the best possible place would be in the `template_redirect` action. I could probably call `add_action()` from where the 404 error is being thrown right now and hook in a function that sets the query to 404.