# Rewrite rules for varying nested terms of custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms, rewrite-rules, hierarchical

I've searched the net an the only working solution to this seems to be [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types/39862#39862) by Jeff which does everything except handle nested terms.

Does anybody know how to change the rewrite based on the term depth?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hierarchical-urls/). It provides hierarchical URLs for categories, but you can easily adapt to any taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks but there aren't any plugins which support custom taxonomy hierarchy - builtin categories tax is different, I wish they did work in that way!

Comment: Hey, wait. Just saw that maybe I implemented this for all taxonomies, just didn't remember. Take a look. =D

Comment: I installed it..looks good but didn't help me I'm afraid. It would need to make the permalinks match the hierarchy which is what I'm having so much difficulty with.