# Append custom parameter to taxonomy/term URI

Tags: urls, rewrite-rules, advanced-taxonomy-queries, rewrite-tag

I have a **Custom Post Type** named "**Cars**" and **2 Custom Taxonomies** "**Ferrari**" and "**Lamborghini**". Each taxonomy has **2 Terms**: "**New**" and "**Used**".

These URIs work as expected:

```
http://myhost/ferrari/new
http://myhost/ferrari/used
```

The problem is, of course, when I append the car ID at the end I get a **404**:

```
http://myhost/ferrari/new/123
```

I've been playing a lot with **add_rewrite_rule/add_rewrite_tag** and read many discussions here on **StackExchange** but I couldn't find a solution. I also tried [WP Router](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-router/) and it actually works, but it almost entirely overrides the default routing so that it feels like a hack.

**Question:**

All I need is being able to route the URI with the appended ID to the same template as it would without, so from there I can make a custom query using the ID segment.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to follow this question and it's solution: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
function my_car_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
    $newrules = array();

    // add a rule for this kind of url:
    // http://myhost.com/cars/ferrari/used/123
    // => http://myhost.com/index.php?post_type=cars&ferrari=used&p=123 

    $newrules['^cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=cars&$matches[1]=$matches[2]&p=$matches[3]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','my_car_rewrite_rules');
```

and remember to "save the permalinks" when testing.

I added **/cars/** so this rewrite will not overwrite your other pages.

You can also try this more restrict rule:

```
$newrules['^cars/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=cars&$matches[1]=$matches[2]&p=$matches[3]';
```

or even

```
$newrules['^cars/([ferrari|lamborghini]+)/([used|new]+)/([0-9]+)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=cars&$matches[1]=$matches[2]&p=$matches[3]';
```

To remove the CPT from URI (need to do it for each taxonomy)

```
$newrules['^ferrari/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=cars&$ferrari=$matches[1]&p=$matches[2]';
```

Comment: Brilliant! I've also added a modified rule to allow taxonomy/term/id, instead of cpt/taxonomy/term/id. Thank you very much.

Comment: ok great ;-) (I approved your edit so it should show up now)