# URL Rewrite and add_query_var not working

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I know there are several topics about URL rewriting in Wordpress but none of the topics I found helped me.

I want to rewrite the URL

```
profile/?person=abc (which works fine, but isn't pretty)
```

to

```
profile/abc
```

This is what I added to the functions.php of my theme:

```
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_rule('profile/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=profile&person=$matches[1]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);
}
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');

function add_query_vars() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('person');
}
add_action('init', 'add_query_vars');
```

When I try to call

```
mydomain.com/profile/abc
```

Wordpress just changes the URL to

```
mydomain.com/profile
```

Of course 'person' is not among the query vars when I try to access them.

I also tried to write everything in one function (which shouldn't make any difference) and to add the query var 'person' to the query array with the query_vars filter hook:

```
function add_query_vars($q) {
    $q[] = 'person';
    return $q;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

From everything I've read about URL rewriting with WP my code should work. I also tried deactivating all other plugins so nothing could interfere.

### Solution

Since I can't answer my question because of my reputation I write the solution here:

The reason was that I tried to redirect to a child page. I left that piece of information out in my code above because I thought it was unimportant, but in fact it was the reason for my issue. Sorry for that, I just wanted to clean my code up a bit :-/

The line that got it all working:

```
add_rewrite_rule('persons/profile/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=persons/profile&person=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

What I don't understand is why I didn't get any error messages (WP_DEBUG was set to true) and got redirected to the right page (just without query parameter).

Comment: have you refreshed the rewrite rules? in your code it says it is set to false, another way of doing this is by saving the permalinks again on `admin > settings> permalinks` even without changing anything..

Comment: Yes, I did that. The rewrite rule itself seems to work, but it ignores the added query_var.

Comment: i am using the code from here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types and it works.. see the function `mmp_rewrite_rules` and i can make the query var work. another thing, is your profile a custom post type? didn't you just add the `'query_var' => 'person'` args when registering that post type?

Comment: btw i am having a problem with rewrite too.. see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102246/wordpress-returns-404-on-custom-rewrite-rules ;P

Comment: The filter `rewrite_rules_array` doesn't work for me. That was the first thing I tried but it never entered the callback function. I also found that newer tutorials and documents about rewrite rules didn't use that filter anymore. I'm using WP 3.5.1. if that makes any difference.

Comment: im using 3.5.1 too, and i dont know why but it's working still for me now..

Comment: I just tried your way again and now the rewrite rule works. I don't know why my first attempt failed..
However, my real problem still exists. WP just ignores my added query vars and removes them from the URL.