# Wordpress returns 404 on custom rewrite rule conflict in parameters

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, regex

I have been following the steps on the [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) and it worked wonders.

But my problem is on this part,

on the original:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules['custom-post-type-base/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?custom_post_type_name=$matches[4]'; // my custom structure will always have the post name as the 5th uri segment
    $newRules['custom-post-type-base/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?taxonomy_name=$matches[1]'; 

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

my version:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules['custom-post-type-base/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?custom_post_type=$matches[3]'; 
    $newRules['custom-post-type-base/(.+)/?$']           = 'index.php?custom_taxonomy=$matches[1]';

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

Since my taxonomy has two levels, it couldn't recognize whether the 2nd param (`custom-post-type-base/(.+)/[here]/`) is a custom post or a custom taxonomy..
it returns correctly on custom taxonomy but returns 404 on a custom post type with the post type being categorized on the parent taxonomy.

See Sample URLS:

```
"/custom-post-type-base/taxonomy-parent/taxonomy-child/single-custom-post-type/"
/*works as single custom post*/

"/custom-post-type-base/taxonomy-parent/taxonomy-child/"
/*works as custom taxonomy page*/

"/custom-post-type-base/taxonomy-parent/"
/*works as custom taxonomy page too*/

"/custom-post-type-base/taxonomy-parent/single-custom-post-type/"
/*returns a 404*/
```

Comment: have you flushed rewrite rules?

Comment: yes, im doing it everytime i update my code..

Comment: Does it match in monkeyman rewrite analyser?

Comment: what is that? o.O? it matches the taxonomy part, the problem is if instead of a taxonomy a custom post is in the parameter.. so i need a switch that would allow both custom tax and custom post type on the 2nd param `#basename/(.+)/[here]/(.+)/?$#`

Comment: in other words, the custom post type can be both on the 2nd and 3rd param, the taxonomy is two levels so adding the post type in the child taxonomy works, but adding it to the parent taxonomy would render a 404..

Comment: it's a plugin that is extremely useful for rewrite rules, you put in a URL and it shows you which rules match and in priority order, and what is extracted. Your rule may well match but be too broad or too late in the process and another rule catches it

Comment: hmmm wait you want the custom post type as the second parameter? But this suggests your problem has nothing to do with your question. Your question says I have rewrite rules X but get a 404, not, how do I put the custom post type in this rewrite rule

Comment: Hey did you find the solution for this @reikyoushin

Answer (score 1):

You have:

- A rewrite rule that handles the post being in the 5th part
- A rewrite rule to handle the taxonomy part

A rewrite rule to handle the post being in the 2nd or 3rd part isn't in the above list, hence why you get a 404.

If we take this rewrite rule:

```
$newRules['basename/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?custom_post_type_name=$matches[4]'; // my custom structure will always have the post name as the 5th uri segment
```

And modify it slightly using some common sense, namely:

- basename/***(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)***/?$ ....

  custom_post_type_name=$matches[***4***]

  // my custom structure will always have the post name as the ***5*** th uri segment
- basename/***(.+)/(.+)/(.+)***/?$ ....

  custom_post_type_name=$matches[***3***]

  // my custom structure will always have the post name as the ***4*** th uri segment
- basename/***(.+)/(.+)***/?$ ....

  custom_post_type_name=$matches[***2***]

  // my custom structure will always have the post name as the ***3*** th uri segment

etc

Place these in ascending order prior to your existing rule, and repeat as many times as is necessary

Comment: ooops, i've already adjusted my code from the original (will post my code on top), i dont get a 404 on the 2nd and 3rd sample url. please see. thanks!

Comment: the only time i get a 404 is when the post is under the parent taxonomy, if its under the child taxonomy everything is fine..