# Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I am having trouble working with WordPress rewrite rules, and could use some help.

I have a custom post type called `_shows_`.

All *shows* have a single custom taxonomy category `_show-category_.` A `_show_` will never have more than one `_show-category_`.

I would like my urls to route in this manner:

```
www.mysite.com/shows/  =>  archive-shows.php

www.mysite.com/shows/%category%/ => taxonomy-show-category.php

www.mysite.com/shows/%category%/%postname%/ => single-shows.php
```

So as a real world example, lets say we have a `_show-category_` "Foo" and a `_show_` post titled "Bar" that has "Foo" as it's `_show-category_`. I would expect my WordPress app to look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/shows/foo/ => shows all posts under the foo category
www.mysite.com/shows/foo/bar => shows the indivual post
```

I try to avoid plugins when possible, but am open to any solution.

Comment: just pointing you to something i had to do before.. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102246/wordpress-returns-404-on-custom-rewrite-rule-conflict-in-parameters

Comment: Brilliant question, and the accepted answer by @Milo is so well done it really should be in official Wordpress documentation. This is a VERY common use case for proper URLs.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First, [register your taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) and set the `slug` argument of `rewrite` to `shows`:

```
register_taxonomy(
    'show_category',
    'show',
    array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'shows', 'with_front' => false ),
        // your other args...
    )
);
```

Next, [register your post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and set the slug to `shows/%show_category%`, and set `has_archive` argument to `shows`:

```
register_post_type(
    'show',
    array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'shows/%show_category%', 'with_front' => false ),
        'has_archive' => 'shows',
        // your other args...
    )
);
```

Last, add a filter to `post_type_link` to substitute the show category in individual show permalinks:

```
function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'show' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'show_category' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%show_category%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

**EDIT**

Forgot the `has_archive` argument of `register_post_type` above, that should be set to `shows`.

Comment: Milo, thank you! The post_type_link filter was the missing piece for me. Anyone reading this thread with the same problem, the only thing of note is there is a small mistake on the wpa_show_permalinks function, where $post->post_type == 'show' should actually be 'shows'. Thanks again Milo!

Comment: Thanks, Milo! That solved my problem. I was trying to achieve something similar using the [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/) and the rewritten URLs were getting 404. I guess manually doing it was the right way.

Comment: @milo, coming over from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199456/custom-taxonomy-post-slug-permalink, I keep landing on a `404` with this approach. My permalink structure is `%category%/%postname%`

Comment: If you're making a change to an existing WordPress instance, make sure you go to Settings > Permalinks and click save. The changes you've made in functions.php won't take effect until you do.

Comment: This almost worked for me in that the taxonomy displays on the post type page, the /post_type/taxonomy/ is a legitimate page (previously 404) but my /post_type/taxonomy/post is 404'ing.  I noticed when registering the taxonomy above both "show_category", "show" were being registered, even though only the show_category is the taxonomy. I'm only registering the taxonomy.

Comment: @Milo  any way to get this to work with sub sub tax like 
shows/tax/subtax/post ?

Comment: I too would be interested in knowing how to get this to work with taxonomy children like `/shows/tax/subtax/postname`

Comment: This is a really valuable technique, thank you. There's a little problem anyway: by using the 'post_type_link', the modify/edit button on admin's post edit view, will disappear. Meaning that the post's slug won't be editable, and so, that slug will be fixed and if you'll change the post_title later, you won't be able to mirror it on the slug.

Comment: How (internally) does 'shows/%show_category%' automatically resolve to the right taxonomy/term? I'm just curious. Official register_post_type docs do not explain, nor give you any information and instead let believe we only can pass regular strings instead of full permastructures.
Also, I can't find any doc about auto-generating permastructure tags upon taxonomy creation.

Comment: @Stratboy I'll have to try it again, I don't recall the post slug not being editable in this case. I know with more complex structures I've had to use `add_permastruct` instead. WP doesn't do anything with `%show_category%` in this case, it's just a placeholder that you have to replace yourself in the `post_type_link` filter. This can actually be any valid rewrite tag, for example if you want to use a custom field or something else in the URL.

Comment: In fact, if you take a look to $wp_rewrite right after registering the post types but before the `post_type_link` filter, you'll notice that the %show_category% tag has been generated, as well as the related permastructures. So it's strange, they exist, so they get recognized but probably wordpress doesn't know how to treat them.

Comment: @stratboy show_category has to be a valid rewrite tag, which it is, because that was added as part of registering the taxonomy, but it can also just be one added via add_rewrite_tag. It's doing the same thing behind the scenes.

Comment: What happens when you need slug different in various languages? (WPML for instance). And when certain posts don't have a category set, will they still have just /shows/post-name ? Cheers!

Comment: In WPML case this works for default language but unfortunately not in others

Comment: I so wished this would work for me as well but every singular ends in a 404....

Comment: This is just resulting in 404s for me too, unfortunately... even after refreshing permalinks.

Comment: WordPress 5.2.4 & WordPress 5.3 resulted in 404's for this solution as well. I've posted a WP Support forum question asking if anyone else might have some knowledge in what changed in rewrites in the last few years that might have broken this ability.

I'm using a plugin to manage the permalink structure now and it seems that the plugin is doing some wp_query parsing to make the permalinks work correctly.

Comment: I had the same 404 issue on individual show post pages as commented by other users, but was able to work around it by adding `add_rewrite_rule( 'shows/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', 'index.php?show =$matches[2]', 'top' );` to my functions. This will match the second slug portion after 'show' to a show post name.

Comment: Milo's solution almost works. Unfortunately the post type is lost and the default template is used instead of the CPT.

Comment: This almost worked for me – the main post type page and the category pages were working fine, but it was failing on the posts! (WP thought the post was a sub-category, and returned a 404.) The missing step was the ```rewrite_rules_array``` filter, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702560/915762

Comment: There is a bummer, you can't have same slugs for different taxonomies e.g `/post-type/taxonomy-1/seo-agency/` and `/post-type/taxonomy-2/seo-agency/` won't be possible

Comment: @Sarah OMG you are my SAVIOR! This is working now, finally OMG! Thank you thank you! I had a use case very similar in that I had a resource post type with resource_category taxonomy. The taxonomy pages worked and the archive worked, but the singles did not. This worked: `add_rewrite_rule( '^resources/([^/]+)/([^/]+)', 'index.php?resource=$matches[2]', 'top' );`