# Adding rewrite rules to Custom Post-type mixed with Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules

I turn to you because I can not find any solution to my problem.

I created 3 custom post types **"Actualités"**, **"Dossiers"**, **"Vidéos"** (I'm french :D)

I created 1 taxonomy: **"Thématiques"** with the following terms:

- Santé
- Géopolitique
- ...

**And I would like to get links like this *(see below - example with CPT: "Dossiers" and tax: "Santé")* :**

- www.url.com/dossiers/sante/nom-de-larticle **=>** Display the post *(single)*
- www.url.com/dossiers/sante/ **=>** Display posts of post type "Dossiers" with tax "Santé" *(archive)*
- www.url.com/dossiers/ **=>** Display all posts of post type "Dossiers" *(archive)*
- www.url.com/sante/ **=>** Display all posts of taxonomy "Santé" *(archive)*

And the same thing for "Videos" and "Actualités".

**For now I achieve this with non rewritten urls:**

- www.url.com/?dossiers=nom-de-larticle
- www.url.com/?post_type=dossiers&thematiques=sante
- www.url.com/?post_type=dossiers
- www.url.com/?thematiques=sante

How can I achieve this by manipulating my functions.php? Or adding rewrite rules?

This is my code for Custom Post-Type "Dossiers" *(I done the same for "Videos" and "Actualités")* :

```
function register_cpt_dossiers() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Dossiers', 'dossiers' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Dossier', 'dossiers' ),
        'all_items' => _x( 'Tous les dossiers', 'dossiers' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Ajouter', 'dossiers' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Ajouter un nouveau dossier', 'dossiers' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Modifier le dossier', 'dossiers' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Nouveau dossier', 'dossiers' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Afficher le dossier', 'dossiers' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Chercher dans les dossiers', 'dossiers' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Aucun dossier trouvé.', 'dossiers' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Aucun dossier trouvé dans la corbeille.', 'dossiers' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Magazine parent :', 'dossiers' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Dossiers', 'dossiers' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'thematiques'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => 'dossiers',
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'dossiers/%thematiques%', 'hierarchical' => true ),
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'dossiers', $args );
}
```

And this is my code for the Taxonomy "Thématiques" :

```
register_taxonomy(
    'thematiques',
    array( 'post', 'dossiers','videos' ),
    array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'dossiers' ),
    'label' => 'Thématiques',
    'query_var' => true
    )
);
```

And the function for permalinks :

```
function wpa_show_permalinks( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'dossiers' ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'thematiques' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%thematiques%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_show_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108647/4771) for how to get a taxonomy term in a cpt permalink. your desired url for taxonomy term `www.url.com/sante/` will clash with page rewrite rules and cause them to 404, it's far simpler to have `www.url.com/thematiques/sante/`.

Comment: I did exactly what you said in the answer but it works only for `www.url.com/dossiers/sante/nom-de-larticle`. Thank you Milo for your help

Comment: I added "theme" to `www.url.com/sante/` so now it's `www.url.com/theme/sante/` and it show good but not the rest => `www.url.com/dossiers/sante/` and `www.url.com/dossiers/`

Comment: update your question with your current code.

Comment: for the cpt, `has_archive` should be `dossiers`, and if you want the taxonomy terms to be available under `dossiers/term/`, then the taxonomy slug should also be `dossiers`.

Comment: Code updated but i'm not sure is good.

Comment: `dossiers/sante/` show me now all post from sante, but i want all dossiers posts from sante

Comment: ah sorry, I missed that part of your explanation. I think you will have to [add a rewrite rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) for each cpt to handle those requests.

Comment: `I tried that : add_rewrite_rule("^dossier/([^/]+)/?",'index.php?post_type=dossiers&thematiques=$matches[1]','top');` But it crashes me posts :( and url.com/theme/sante doesnt work anymore.

Comment: No ideas? I'm still blocked :(

Comment: Resolved by buying this plugin: http://www.gdcpttools.com/features/