# After rewriting post type's URL, the number of queries has increased dramatically

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I rewrited the URL of post type, and the main loop ( example.com/post-type/ ) generates an expensive number of queries.

So I have a post type "cd" and taxonomy "artist", and the url are:

- example.com/cd
- example.com/cd/artist/name-cd
- example.com/cd/artist

The code...

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'cd_type_link', 1, 3 );
function cd_type_link($link,$post) {
    global $post;
    $post_type = 'cd';
    $taxonomy = 'artist';

    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
    $slug = $terms[0]->slug;

    $post_name = $post->post_name;

    if ( $post->post_type == $post_type ) {
        $link = get_post_type_archive_link($post_type) ."/{$slug}/{$post_name}";
    }
    return $link;
}
```

......................................................

```
add_action('init', 'new_add_rules');
function new_add_rules() {    
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^cd/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?',
        'index.php?post_type=cd&cd=$matches[2]&artist=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^cd/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?post_type=cd&artist=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

The loop in archive-cd.php :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Without url rewrite, the queries are low. With url rewrite, the queries are high.
The problem is "the_permalink()", because if I leave the function the_permalink(), the number of queries drops significantly.

How can I resolve? Thanks.

Comment: `the_permalink()` doesn't appear in the code you posted?

Comment: It is hard to say what is happening without more information. For now you should avoid to run `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` in every `init` because perfomance cost. Also you should pass `false` argument to `flush_rules();` to avoid rewrite .htaccess file in every call (I think yo don't it). See the description of [`flush_rules()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules) in the Codex.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I added the loop of archive-cd.php into main post.

Comment: well you are querying for the terms associated with a post to output the post's permalink, so that will add queries. it's also worth noting that adding rewrite rules to handle this is redundant, you added rewrite rules with the registration of your post type and taxonomy, you can define the pattern there with the `rewrite` argument and get rid of the `add_rewrite_rule` stuff. lots of examples of that on this site if you search around.

Comment: @cybnet I saw the code and I delete the only function "flush_rules()" in my files and the queries are lower than before, but when I add another post type "cd", the num_queries always increases.

Comment: @Milo Yes, but I have a problem... When I use that code (for example: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post/108647#108647] ), the archive "cd" doesn't work...

Comment: it's likely the order you're registering things in, I'd have to see that code. anyway, regarding queries, the number of them is mostly irrelevant, all that's important are the queries themselves. you can run 100 fast queries in less time than 1 complex query.