# Arduous Wordpress Custom Post Type Permalink Path

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

once again folks, i have to ask about custom post type url, because is not clear for me what to do so let me short eplain whats the problem is with it

Note:

I have seen a lot of solutions (here) to reach the same goal, and that's confuses me as i'm a wordpress/php novice. Nothing or most i tryed worked that way i like to have it, to say: it's even not clear anymore if i should go with the settings that comes out of the box with wordpress for better seo purposes.

i tried to have this natural construct in the path:

websitename/myproducts/productclass/productname

domain/cpt/tax/post

so, all kind of constructs i have made, most, the click on the product itself shows the post in is single.php as

websitename/myproducts/productname

and  it's for me clear, that i d'ont wana have the registred tax-name itself:

websitename/myproduct/productclass/tables/woodtable-nr009

it should have this in:

websitename/myproducts/tables/woodtable-nr009

the tax itself shouldn't be shown as name but as product category-name added.

i hope there's somebody has time to explain me what i should do, or even is better to go with the default, so there would never be a 404 because i deleted the post (product) if its sold out, but allways there is the category tables with some few other posts in it.

sorry for asking twice, but even with the custom post type plugin i d'ont get the result explained above. hope it's somewhat clear enough what i mean.

thank you.

Comment: [something like this?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108647/4771)

Comment: i'll try again (i'm pretty sure i have made it that way) but thank you again for the link!

Comment: people will be able to help you if you try something and then edit your question to show the code you're working with. also always develop with [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and provide any error messages your code generates.

Comment: @Milo this worked for me finally! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's not the wrong Way to answer this Question by myself. The post from Milo has helped me defintely:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108647/63272

I once made this otherwise:

```
'has_archive' => 'myproducts',
```

before i have allways set this to: true, because i may have not quite understand it.

If you also have troubles with this, try set this arg in your reg. cpt to: post-type-name-slug. I d'ont know what's the difference to the default used value.