# Custom taxonomy & post slug permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have a custom taxonomy and a custom post type. I'm aiming for the following permalink structure:

`{custom taxonomy}/{custom taxonomy term}/{custom post slug}`

Or, at the very least,

`{custom taxonomy term}/{custom post slug}`

I currently have

`{%category%}/{%postname%}`, but no dice.

For example, assume I have:

- a taxonomy `states`, and a taxonomy term `newyork`
- a custom post type `jobs` with a post that has the slug `wordpress-developer`

I am looking to achieve:

- `states/newyork`: an archive of all the `jobs` in `newyork`, this works.
- `states/newyork/wordpress-developer`: the custom post's page using the taxonomy & term as the base in the permalink.

The goal is to navigate from `states/newyork` (list of "jobs" and flow into the individual post w/o deviating from the permalink structure thus far, so `states/newyork/wordpress-developer`

Problems encountered:

- `states/newyork/wordpress` yields a `404`
- `newyork/wordpress-developer` redirects to `jobs/wordpress-developer`

Desired outcome:

- `states/newyork/wordpress-developer` landing on the custom post type page

PS - not building another job board, just using this as an example :)

---

current taxonomy & post type register hook:

```
function register() {
  register_taxonomy('state', 'district', array(
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'States',
      'singular_name' => 'State',
      'search_items' => 'Search States',
      'all_items' => 'All States',
      'parent_item' => 'Parent State',
      'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent State:',
      'edit_item' => 'Edit State',
      'update_item' => 'Update State',
      'add_new_item' => 'Add New State',
      'new_item_name' => 'New State',
      'menu_name' => 'States'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
      'slug' => 'states',
      'with_front' => false
    )
  ));

  register_post_type('district',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Districts',
        'singular_name' => 'Districts'
      ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'supports' => array('title', 'page-attributes'),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => 'states',
      'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => false,
        'slug' => 'states/%show_category%'
      )
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)

Comment: @Milo I had tried that, looked very promising, but it resulted in a `404`

Comment: The order that you register things is important. Add the code you tried to your question. Also note that your posts permalink structure is irrelevant, that's only the native `post` type.

Comment: Updated @Milo. I have the taxonomy, then the post type. I have also tried this in the opposite order

Comment: A big red flag was looking at the `$wp_query` object on the `404` template. The `request` property appears to not identify the custom post type: `SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'district-1' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC`

Comment: @Atticus Did you flush your rewrite rules after trying the other question's answer? (i.e. go to Settings > Permalinks > Save)

Comment: Yes, @TheDeadMedic. I make sure to flush after any changes to the rewrite system

Comment: `%show_category%` should be `%state%`, it needs to match the query var of your taxonomy.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by defining a rewrite rule:

```
function rewrite_rules($rules) {
  $newRules = array();
  $newRules['states/(.+)/(.+?)$'] = 'index.php?district=$matches[2]';
  return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\rewrite_rules');
```