# Wordpress modify Settings > Permalinks (options-permalink.php) Add CPT Permalink Options

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, settings-api, options

How do I modify the `Settings > Permalinks (options-permalink.php)` admin page to add more custom permalink parameters? I'd like to add additional permalink parameters to the "Optional" section for custom taxonomies that I've created.  Specifically, I'd like to add more base prefix options for the Custom Taxonomies that I created. The custom taxonomies are named 'topic' and 'team-category'. How can I go about doing this?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You have a free wordpress plugin made for that:
[Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

Let us know if it is convenient

Comment: @corey if you need more customisation, look this function :http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section

Comment: The plugin is nice but I was wanting to know how to accomplish this from a code level

Comment: Ok. So may be you are looking for something like this: [How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) and this one [Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post) and this one too [Custom taxonomy & post slug permalink](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199456/custom-taxonomy-post-slug-permalink)

Comment: One more : [Custom permalink structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698827/custom-permalink-structure-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post-name)