# Custom post type with custom taxonomy permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, loop

I've looked around but can't find a decent solution.

I have a custom post type that adds businesses.  In the loop it will list all by default but I want to be able to attach an event category to each custom post so I can filter on separate pages by that event.

Basically each custom post will have a category assigned.  So event 'PartyOne' will have custom post with details, a FAQ, Sponsor list.

I have custom posts for sponsor list and FAQ but is there a way to group them all together?  So when they hit the PartyOne page, it links the FAQ, Sponsors and the post content for that event?

I thought of registering the custom post type then assinging the url with the category so mysite.com/partyone/exhibiting/businessname but when I make the custom post it only writes mysite.com/exhibiting/businessname where I need 'partyone' as a cat to bind them all together here is what I have so far

```
// Register custom taxonomy before post type
function add_event_taxonomies() {

        register_taxonomy('event', 'exhibitors', array(
                // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
                'hierarchical' => true,
                // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
                'labels' => array(
                        'name' => _x( 'Exhibitor Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                        'singular_name' => _x( 'Exhibitor-Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Exhibitor-Categories' ),
                        'all_items' => __( 'All Exhibitor-Categories' ),
                        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Exhibitor-Category' ),
                        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Exhibitor-Category:' ),
                        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Exhibitor-Category' ),
                        'update_item' => __( 'Update Exhibitor-Category' ),
                        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Exhibitor-Category' ),
                        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Exhibitor-Category Name' ),
                        'menu_name' => __( 'Exhibitor Categories' ),
                ),
                // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
                'rewrite' => array(
                        'slug' => 'exhibitors/%category%', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                        'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
                        'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
                ),
        ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_event_taxonomies', 0 );

// Register Exhibitors Post Type 
function exhibitors_init() {
    $args = array(
      'label' => 'Exhibitors',
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'exhibitors'),
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-megaphone',
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions',
            'thumbnail',
            'page-attributes'),

        );
    register_post_type( 'exhibitors', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'exhibitors_init' );
```

So it registers a custom category for Exhibitors but when I create a new post it wont attach the category to the permalink.  Any ideas?  Also if there is a better solution I am open to starting over

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WordPress Types have that features](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/). So, you don't need to code by yourself or use [custom post type generator](https://generatewp.com/post-type/). I hope you would get answer in there. Sorry for quick answers without modification your codes :)