# Change the url of Projects in Divi Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, urls

I use the Divi Theme for a Wordpress website. At the moment, everything in Projects Custom Post, have the same url in the following format:

`www.mywebsite.com/projects/project-name`

What I tried to do is to change the `projects` to a more dynamic name based on the category a project belongs. I know that I can just create a few more custom posts, but I prefer to keep it like this.

I tried to change the permalink settings to `/%category%/` but then my projects didn't work with either of the two versions.

I tried also this way, but it just changes to a new static name, without the category dynamic url:

```
<?php
function custom_post_name () {
return array(
'feeds' => true,
'slug' => 'anewname',
'with_front' => false,
);
}
add_filter( 'et_project_posttype_rewrite_args', 'custom_post_name' );
?>
```

Is there any advice to achieve this or I should turn to different custom posts?

**Example:**

I have two projects (a custom post type of divi theme) with the categories: `foods` and `drinks`. At the moment, the url of them are the following

1. www.mydomain.com/projects/foodexample1
2. www.mydomain.com/projects/drinkexample2

I want to make them as:

1. www.mydomain.com/foods/foodexample1
2. www.mydomain.com/drinks/drinkexample2

Comment: You need to do a little extra work to use taxonomy terms in CPT URLs, [see this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108647/4771).

Comment: What is your desired output? please explain in clear examples what do u expect to have

Comment: @Trix Added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the taxonomies (like category or any other custom taxonomies, registered for the custom post type, using register_taxonomy function ), to be part of single post permalinks in wordpress, you may use the following code in your `functions.php` of the current theme:

```
function my_post_type_link( $post_link, $post ){
    if( !empty( $post->post_type ) && in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'projects' ) ) ){
        $slug = $post->post_name;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $post_cats = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );     
        if( !empty( $post_cats[0] ) ){
            $target_category = $post_cats[0];
            while( !empty( $target_category->slug ) ){
                $slug = $target_category->slug . '/' . $slug;
                if( !empty( $target_category->parent ) ){
                    $target_category = get_term( $target_category->parent, 'category' );
                }else{
                    break;
                }
            }
            $post_link = get_option( 'home' ) . '/'. urldecode( $slug );
        }
    }
    return  $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'my_post_type_link', 10, 2 );

function my_pre_get_posts( $q ){     
    if( $q->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && $q->is_single ){
        $q->set( 'post_type',  array_merge( array( 'post' ), array( 'projects' ) )   );
    }
    return $q;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts', 10 );
```

Using this, you may have the desired output, for your `projects` posts' permalinks.

Comment: I will check it later today and let you know :)