# Divi change project slug based on category

Tags: categories, slug

My first help-question here :)

Using Divi theme, i found that Project custom post type let you add your portfolio projects, while having PROJECT slug in the URL.
The web is full of tutorial about changing that slug, but i'd love tu change the project slug with the **category** of that posted project.

I found this on StackExchange but it didn't work out for me :( [Change the url of Projects in Divi Theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212455/change-the-url-of-projects-in-divi-theme)

My issue is the same:

- I have 2 different project with 2 different categories. Project 1 with Category A, and Project 2 with Category B.
- The url, right now, is homepage.com/project/project-1
- I'd love to be homepage.com/category-a/project-1 and homepage.com/category-b/project-2

Is it even possible?

Thank you for your time and your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Post Type Permalinks extension. Open breadcrumbs settings and add /%project_category% in Permalink Settings for Custom Post Types. Save. Done. That's how I figured it out.