# Divi change project category slug

Tags: php, permalinks, url-rewriting, child-theme

## How to change taxonomy urls in wordpress?

Following along with [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296510/divi-change-project-slug-based-on-category) and [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212455/change-the-url-of-projects-in-divi-theme)

But can not get the desired outcome.

**The default is:**

```
example.com/project_category/%category%/
```

**What I want is:**

```
example.com/stainless-steel-products/%category%/
```

I have changed the slug of the project archive so that `example.com/stainless-steel-products/` is the project archive.

Below is the code used to achieve that.

```
// Change peralinks projects
function custom_project_slug () {
    return array(
    'feeds' => true,
    'slug' => 'stainless-steel-products',
    'with_front' => false,
    );
}
add_filter( 'et_project_posttype_rewrite_args', 'custom_project_slug' );

?>
```

How do I change the slug of the project categories so that it is a child of the project archive?
Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'register_taxonomy_args', 'change_taxonomies_slug', 10, 2 );
function change_taxonomies_slug( $args, $taxonomy ) {

   if ( 'project_category' === $taxonomy ) {
      $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'stainless-steel-products';
   }

   return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

It works fine. U only need also to add this in function php:

```
// Change peralinks projects
function custom_project_slug () {
    return array(
    'feeds' => true,
    'slug' => 'stainless-steel-products',
    'with_front' => false,
    );
}
add_filter( 'et_project_posttype_rewrite_args', 'custom_project_slug' );
```