# How to show custom taxonomy in the permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, categories

I used the Portfolio Post Type Plugin to create custom tax and post type.

I would like to show the custom taxonomy on the portfolio projects.

portfolio/customtaxonomy/project

while now is

portfolio/project

I know the regular post type permalink setting is in the wordpress setting page, I would like to do the same but showing the custom taxonomy (portfolio_category) instead of the normal category.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)

Comment: I can't find the registered post type in function, sorry. Maybe because I used the plugin? I don't understand where should I look and what to add

Comment: If that plugin doesn't let you modify the post type parameters, then you'll need to [register the post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) yourself.