# Custom Post Type rewrite url to /category/pagetitle

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I know this questions has been asked a lot, but after working on it for 6 hours straight I can not find a good solutions anywhere.

My site has a Custom Post Type and taxonomy. My taxonomy are for example HP, Dell and Asus. Every product has checked there taxonomy. Now I need to rewrite my url to give me a different link (ie `products/$taxonomy/$productname`), so the outcome should be `products/asus/n56jn`. Asus is the taxonomy, n56jn is the product name.

**Functions.php**

**Register Post Type**

```
function site_add_cpt() {
  register_post_type( 'cpt_products', array(
  'labels'            =>  array(
    'name'          =>      __( 'Products' ),
    'singular_name' =>      __( 'Product' ),
    'all_items'     =>      __( 'View Products' ),
    'add_new'       =>      __( 'New Product' ),
    'add_new_item'  =>      __( 'New Product' ),
    'edit_item'     =>      __( 'Edit Product' ),
    'view_item'     =>      __( 'View Product' ),
    'search_items'  =>      __( 'Search Products' ),
    'no_found'      =>      __( 'No Products Found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Products in Trash' )
    ),
    'public'            =>  true,
    'publicly_queryable'=>  true,
    'show_ui'           =>  true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' =>  true,
    'capability_type'   =>  'page',
    'hierarchical'      =>  true,
    'rewrite'           =>  array( 'slug' => '%product_item%', 'with_front' => false ),
    'menu_icon'         =>  'dashicons-cart',
    'menu_position'     =>  21,
    'supports'          =>  array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'revisions' ),
) );

  );
}
add_action('init', 'site_add_cpt');
```

**Register Taxonomy**

```
function site_add_tax() {
  register_taxonomy(
    'tax_products',
    'cpt_products',
    array(
      'labels'            =>  array(
      'name'              => __( 'Product Categories' ),
      'singular_name'     => __( 'Product Category' ),
      'search_items'      => __( 'Search Product Categories' ),
      'all_items'         => __( 'All Product Categories' ),
      'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Product Category' ),
      'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Product Category:' ),
      'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Product Category' ),
      'update_item'       => __( 'Update Product Category' ),
      'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Product Category' ),
      'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Product Category' ),
      'menu_name'         => __( 'Product Categories' )
      ),
      'public'            =>  true,
      'hierarchical'      =>  true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' =>  true,
      'show_admin_column' =>  true,
      'rewrite'           =>  array( 'slug' => 'products', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => true )
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'site_add_taxt');
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments by Milo (many thanks!) the answer was already posted:
[Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)