# Maintaining WP_Query Relation Among CPT, Custom Taxonomy, Permalinks- CPT UI

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I am using `CPT UI`.
I have created a post type `'books'` and custom taxonomy `'book_categories'`.
I am also using `Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin` for custom url.

- When I click books, url is `http://novice.dev/books` and I can list categories
- When I click category, url is `http://novice.dev/books/book_categories/my_story_books`
- While I click on a post, it is `http://novice.dev/books/thirty-days-and-night`

I have set the url structure like this using `Custom Post Type Permalinks plugin`.

```
http://novice.dev/%cpt%/%custom_taxonomy%/%post%/
```

I tried searching on the net but could not get anything so that I can force keep the bond/find the relation between CPT and Custom Taxonomy.
I want to achieve the following-

1. When I am at archive.php, I can query the custom taxonomy of that post type and hence list all the posts and url as `/%CPT%/`
2. When I am in taxonomy.php, I can get the custom post type slug/name/id and list all the posts related to that category and url as `/%CPT%/%CUSTOM_CATEGORY%/`
3. When I am in single.php, there should be CPT and category there and url as `/%CPT%/%CUSTOM_CATEGORY%/%POST%/`

Individual experiments are successful but I am getting no way or complete reference to maintain the relation between these three. I do not know where I am doing wrong.

Or should I move to core programming?

Comment: [Here is an example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108647/4771) just using code.

Answer (score 0):

Collaborative efforts-

- For `http://novice.dev/books` just create custom post type and check **rewrite** options so that it adds end points.
- For `http://novice.dev/books/book_categories/my_story_books`, create **custom taxonomy** related with the post type and check the options for rewrite options.
- `http://novice.dev/books/thirty-days-and-night` will be automatically when above two are done.