# Adding Custom Taxonomy Along-with Post Name in Post Type Permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

[This](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-include-categories-in-permalinks-for-custom-post-types-cpt/) can solve my problem but after many attempts I am not able to do it. I tried adding `/%book-category%/%post_name%/` to permalink but doesn't work.

I am trying to achieve `books/story-books/story-1`...

#### What could I be missing?

CPT- `books`

CPT Taxonomy- `book-category`

My Code goes here-

add_filter('post_link', 'books_permalink', 1, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'books_permalink', 1, 3);

```
function books_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
  
    if (strpos($permalink, '%book-category%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'book-category');
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0]))
          $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'book';

    return str_replace('%book-category%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

This is digging deep into the wordpress and to my [previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/240610/maintaining-wp-query-relation-among-cpt-custom-taxonomy-permalinks-cpt-ui).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)

Comment: @Milo ofcourse it is duplicate but I want to have solution.

Comment: Well have you tried the code from that answer?

Comment: Hi I am trying but currently I am getting 404 error. That question is well explained. I tried many other answers but that answer is actually to the point for me. :) Thank you.

Comment: I am confident that I will get it done now as I have got the key to do it... :) Thanks a lot @Milo

Comment: @Milo Could 404 error be due to same `post_type_slug` and `post_type_rewrite_slug`? Like you did shows and show...

Comment: It worked for me. **Just had to compromise with hierarchical true** in taxonomy