# How to build overlapping custom post_type and taxonomy rewrites without conflicts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

```
custom post type: gallery

taxonomy: gallery_type (ex terms: photo, video)
```

wanted urls:

```
domain.com/gallery/ > all 'gallery' custom posts

domain.com/gallery/video > all 'gallery' custom posts belonging to 'video' term

domain.com/gallery/video/my-fabulous-gallery-1 > the 'gallery' custom post called 'My Fabulous  Gallery 1'
```

unwanted urls:

```
domain.com/gallery/my-fabulous-gallery-1
```

I think this is quite a common problem. In the past I already solved it in various ways with the use of `add_rewrite_rule()` and some regexp astro-magics. Ok.

BUT:

- Since register_post_type/taxonomy do have a rewrite option (which I usually use for simple things), I wonder: are there more elegant and less involved ways to achieve the results I want?
- Also, after changing the rules/routes/rewrites, I'd like to have wordpress to correctly generate links and things like that, using its standard functions (`get_the_permalink()` etc...). How to?

---

There's an old and quite good article out there:

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies--wp-25488

If you take a look to "Manipulating WordPress Rewrites" you'll see they suggest ways to achieve what I want, but they don't work perfectly. I get the first 2 urls, but this one will not work:

```
domain.com/gallery/video/my-fabulous-gallery-1
```

it will redirect to the standard one:

```
domain.com/gallery/my-fabulous-gallery-1
```

Comment: [This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post) might help you.

Comment: Thank you Milo. 
 
There's one little problem with your technique: by using the 'post_type_link', the modify/edit button on admin's post edit view, will disappear. Meaning that the post's slug won't be editable, so it will be fixed and if you'll later change the post_title, you won't be able to mirror it on the slug. Have you maybe ever solved this issue? I posted a comment even on the other thread.