# Custom post type category pages pagination returns 404

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, pagination, 404-error

I currently have the main posts archive page at `/blog/` (custom permalink structure of `/blog/%postname%/`) and categories at `/blog/category/` (categories base left empty so it defaults to this).

I have a custom post type of `release-notes`, which also shares the `category` taxonomy. The archive page is at `/release-notes/`, and this works fine along with pagination. It was created with CPT UI, and the only properties I changed were `has_archive`, `with_front` and `taxonomies`, so the $args if created manually should be something like:

```
  $args = array(
      'public'              => true,
      'has_archive'         => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'show_in_rest'        => true,
      'rewrite'             => array( 'slug' => 'release-notes', 'with_front' => false ),
      'taxonomies'          => array( 'category' ),
  );
```

The issue I'm having is with the pagination on category pages, e.g. `/release-notes/category/upgrades/`, where pages 2 and beyond return a 404.

To allow for `/release-notes/category/upgrades/` (upgrades category of release-notes custom post type) instead of `/blog/category/upgrades/` (upgrades category of core post type), which WordPress defaults to, I added a rewrite rule for the URL, and I also added a `pre_get_posts` to return only release-notes similar to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/279280/change-category-base-for-custom-post-type-or-posts-page).

```
//Rewrite rule for release notes custom category URL structure
add_rewrite_rule('^release-notes/category/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?&category_name=$matches[1]&is_release-notes_cat=1', 'top');

//Register is_release-notes_cat query variable
function query_vars( $vars ) {
  array_push($vars, 'is_release-notes_cat');
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'query_vars' );

// Modify main query if is_release-notes_cat page
function set_category_archive_release_notes_posts($query) {
  if (is_category() && isset($query->query_vars['is_release-notes_cat'])) {
      if ($query->is_main_query()) {
          // Set the post type to 'release-notes' only for the main query
          $query->set('post_type', 'release-notes');
      }
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_category_archive_release_notes_posts');
```

I'm running the main query in the template file and not a secondary query, so all changes as far as I understand are being made before the query.

```
      <?php if(have_posts()): ?>

        <div class="release-notes__cards">
          <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-release_notes' );

            endwhile;
          ?>
        </div>

        <?php the_posts_pagination(array('class' => 'list--pagination')); ?>

      <?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*the permalink structure for categories set to /blog/category/*" - what is your permalink structure (for the core `post` type) - is it `blog/%category%/%postname%` (which is a Custom Structure)? Or is it `%postname%`, but the **Category base** is `blog/category`? How are you registering the `release-notes` post type, is it via a plugin? Can you add your post type registration code to your question?

Comment: @SallyCJ Sorry, I've updated the question to include the answers to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue I'm having is with the pagination on category pages, e.g.
> `/release-notes/category/upgrades/`, where pages 2 and beyond return a
> 404.

That's because your custom rewrite rule does *not* support paged requests, i.e. it's missing the RegEx ( regular expression pattern ) and query for the `paged` parameter.

So you can either add another rewrite rule which has the above support, or you can use a single RegEx like so:

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    // I added the (?:/page/(\d+))? which is used to match against the page number.
    '^release-notes/category/(.+?)(?:/page/(\d+))?/?$',

    // I added the &paged=$matches[2] so that WordPress knows what the page number is.
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&is_release-notes_cat=1&paged=$matches[2]',

    'top'
);
```

The 404 error should now be gone (after flushing the rewrite rules), however, you don't actually have to add the custom query var named `is_release-notes_cat`.

You could just add `&post_type=release-notes` to your rewrite rule's *query*, like so, and WordPress will know that the post type is `release-notes` when loading your custom category permalink:

```php
add_rewrite_rule(
    // I added the (?:/page/(\d+))? which is used to match against the page number.
    '^release-notes/category/(.+?)(?:/page/(\d+))?/?$',

    // I added the &paged=$matches[2] so that WordPress knows what the page number is.
    // I also removed the &is_release-notes_cat=1 and added &post_type=release-notes.
    'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]&post_type=release-notes',

    'top'
);

/*
 * If you use the above, then you should remove these parts from your code:
 * add_filter( 'query_vars', 'query_vars' );
 * add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_category_archive_release_notes_posts');
 */
```

Comment: Hmm, replacing the code with what you gave gives me a 404 on `/release-notes/category/upgrades/` or any of the other category archive pages. I looked into add_permastruct(), and while I understand that it creates the permalink, I don't quite understand how it knows what to query. Is the permalink structure's name, `release-notes-category` in this case just an identifier and holds no other significance?

Comment: I also realized that shortening my code by just writing `add_rewrite_rule('^release-notes/category/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?&category_name=$matches[1]&post_type=release-notes', 'top');`

with the post type directly in the rewrite rule instead of with the `pre_get_posts` does the same thing as my original code, though `/release-notes/category/upgrades/page/2/` still returns a 404.

I'm also flushing the rewrite rules every time I make a change.

Comment: See the revised answer, and I hope it helps?

Comment: Thank you Sally CJ! It's finally working now. Ah, of course. It makes sense to have to add the paged param too. And yes, I realized the original `pre_get_posts` method was kind of redundant by just adding the post_type query params instead. I'd upvote you if I could, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet. I really appreciate the help though.

Comment: Now (or soon) you can vote up ([see the help page here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)) :) But I'm already grateful enough that you accepted my answer. So thank you and happy coding!

Comment: Great, it's working now. Thanks again :)