# Create Custom Post Type Permalink Structure

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

Is there an easy way to have a permalink structure for Custom Post types that looks like this?

`mysite.com/post-type/` - Listing Page for Post Type

`mysite.com/post-type/taxonomy/` - Category/Taxonomy Listing Page

`mysite.com/post-type/post-name/` - Single Page for Post Type

I have tried the plugin [WP Better Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-better-permalinks/), but it adds a taxonomy to the URL when viewing the single page, which I do not want at all.

Similarly, the inbuilt WordPress permalinks add 'categories', or the name of your custom taxonomy to the URL. Again, not what I want.

Comment: You'll probably find what you're looking for in this post : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of `mysite.com/post-type/` and `mysite.com/post-type/post-name/` is what you want it to be, so you don't need to do anything special there.

To have `mysite.com/post-type/taxonomy/` as the URL for the taxonomy archive, all you need to do is use `'post-type/taxonomy'` as the `rewrite => slug` argument when registering the taxonomy.

Comment: How smart is WP with checking "same" permalink structures? If `example.com/post-type/foo` is requested, but `foo` is not a taxonomy, will it check for posts or give a 404? (and vice versa)

Comment: It's not smart at all. When you register a taxonomy or post type it creates a 'rewrite rule'. Whenever you go to a URL on your WordPress site WordPress will go through these rules and see if the current URL matches. If it matches it will do whatever that rule says to do. If that fails for some reason it won't try the next rule or anything like that, it will just 404.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I actually asked my question wrong, though, haha. When I said `mysite.com/post-type/taxonomy/` I meant `mysite.com/post-type/term/`. An ideas? I can make a new question, or edit the original if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Try searching first, variations on that question are common. It will probably involve creating rewrite rules manually and requests will require extra queries to determine whether to load a term or a post, since the permalink structure is the same.