# Make permalinks based on an ACF-field

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, advanced-custom-fields

This is both a question on 'how to do this', as well as 'should I do this'.

I have the ACF-heavy site, where I would like to make the permalinks based on one of the ACF-fields (let's call it `foo`). If the `foo`-field has the value `123`, then I would like the permalink to that page to be `http://example.org/s123` (the `s` is to avoid the collision with post-id's in the permalink). If that URL is taken, then it should call it `http://example.org/s123-1` and so forth.

The ACF-field is set on a custom post type. And the site contains some important information, so I'd rather leave this functionality out, than to use a plugin. So it needs to be something that goes in the `functions.php`-file.

Is it possible to make this? And is it unwise to mess with WordPress' permalink structure (other that what is allowed in the permalink-settings-page)?

**Addition**

I can see that if you make CPT's have 'root'-permalinks, that that [breaks the permalinks for posts and pages](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304738/permalinks-for-cpt-breaks-permalinks-to-pages). :-/

... I didn't know that it was this hard to let a CPT have a nice/simple permalink.

Comment: Can we leave the "Addition" aside? The addition part is already mentioned in some question here, so I'm not sure if it's worth to solve it once more. And the main part - so just to be clear - you want to generate the permalinks for CPT based on `foo` field instead of `post_title`? The rest of the permalinks logic should be the same (so creating permalinks only during publishing, not changing them later, and so on)?

Comment: Is the permalink linking to a page in particular, is it meant to go to another post or is it meant to append the ACF slug to the CPT url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### URLs made from CF

Well, you can do this in many ways... One of them would be to use `parse_request` filter and modify it's behavior, but it can easily mess something up.

Another way would be to use `save_post` action and modify the posts `post_name`, so WordPress will work like normal, but the `post_name` will be generated based on your custom field and not based on title. This is the solution I would go for. Why? Because then you can use WP functions to assure that the links are unique...

So here's the code:

```
function change_post_name_on_save($post_ID, $post, $update ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $post = get_post( $post_ID );
    $cf_post_name = wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( 's' . get_post_field('foo', $post_ID), $post_ID ), $post_ID, $post->post_status, $post->post_type, $post->post_parent );

    if ( ! in_array( $post->post_status, array( 'publish', 'trash' ) ) ) {
        // no changes for post that is already published or trashed
        $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_name' => $cf_post_name ), array( 'ID' => $post_ID ) );
        clean_post_cache( $post_ID );
    } elseif ( 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {
        if ( $post->ID == $post->post_name ) {
            // it was published just now
            $wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_name' => $cf_post_name ), array( 'ID' => $post_ID ) );
            clean_post_cache( $post_ID );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_name_on_save', 20, 3 );
```

It's not the prettiest one, because ACF fields are saved after the post, so you'll have to overwrite the `post_name` after the post is already saved. But it should work just fine.

### CPTs in root

And there's the second part of your question: How to make CPTs URLs without CPT slug...

WordPress uses Rewrite Rules to parse the request. It means that if the request matches one of the rule, it will be parsed using that rule.

The rule for pages is one of the last rule made to catch most of the requests that didn't match any earlier rules. So if you add your CPT without any slug, then pages rule won't be fired up...

One way to fix this is to register CPT with a slug and then change their links and WPs behavior. Here's the code:

```
function register_mycpt() {
    $arguments = array(
        'label' => 'MyCPT',
        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        ...
        'has_archive' => false,
        'rewrite' => true
    );
    register_post_type('mycpt', $arguments);
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_mycpt' );
```

Now the URLs for these posts will look like these:

```
http://example.com/mycpt/{post_name}/
```

But we can easily change this using `post_type_link` filter:

```
function change_mycpt_post_type_link( $url, $post, $leavename ) {
    if ( 'mycpt' == $post->post_type ) {
        $url = site_url('/') . $post->post_name . '/';
    }

    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'change_mycpt_post_type_link', 10, 3 );
```

Now the URLs will be correct, but... They won't work. They will be parsed using rewrite rule for pages and will cause 404 error (since there is no page with such URL). But we can fix that too:

```
function try_mycpt_before_page_in_parse_request( $wp ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    if ( array_key_exists( 'name', $wp->query_vars ) ) {
        $post_name = $wp->query_vars['name'];

        $id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s AND post_name = %s ",
            'mycpt', $post_name
        ) );

        if ( $id ) {
            $wp->query_vars['mycpt'] = $post_name;
            $wp->query_vars['post_type'] = 'mycpt';
        }

    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'try_mycpt_before_page_in_parse_request' );
```

Comment: First of all... Thanks for your very good and detailed answer. The **CPT's in root**-section works like a charm and is very clever! But I can't get the **URLs made from CF** to work. For some reason, then I can't get the value of the CPT-field (it just names the permalink to be `s` or `s-1`). I tried accessing the var with `get_post_field` another function (hooking onto admin_footer) - and that worked as it should. Is it possible that the `save_post`-hook fires 'too soon' or something? ... Ideally it should write/rewrite the permalink upon every time a user presses 'Publish' or 'Update'.

Comment: This part was tested. But you'll have to be careful - `post_save` is not to soon, BUT, you have to hook with priority set - if you'll use default one (10), then it will be to soon. Setting it for 20 should work fine. That's why there is 20 in here `add_action( 'save_post', 'change_post_name_on_save', 20, 3 );`

Comment: @Zeth have you managed to get it working with changing the priority?

Comment: I haven't had time to dive further down into it, - so it's still not working. When I do have time, then I'll write it here in the comment, so you can potential add my bug to your answer (in case other people encounter it as well). Thanks for your answer and for your assistance.

Comment: Are there a way that I can see what happens inside the 'save_post'-hook, upon pressing 'Publish' or 'Update'? I'm trying to debug it, to see what happens, but it appears that I can only see what that hooks fires upon making a new post, since it creates the auto-draft. Whenever I publish/update, then the result of `'save_post'` is not rendered on the page. So I'm working in the dark, unable to see what happens. I can conclude that this line: `  $cf_post_name = wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( 's'  ...` only returns `s` as a permalink. Any idea on how to debug that?

Comment: I just realized, that I could write `die()` inside that hook. I don't know if it messes with some core stuff, - but it works (I can see what happens inside that hook).

Comment: Ok... I figured it out. The `save_post` fires before the ACF-field is saved to the database, which is why I couldn't get it to work. Which means that that function you've written looks up the ACF-field in the database too soon (and returns an empty string). Plus it doesn't change already-published posts. When I removed the part, that kept the function from rewriting existing published posts' permalinks - and hooked it up on the acf-hook: `acf/save_post`, then I got it to work as intended. I'll post my function in a new comment. Perhaps add it to your answer if anyone else needs it.

Comment: The function is too long. I'll suggest and 'Addition' to your answer.

Comment: @Zeth no, it's not. It depends on the priority you use when you assign the filter (I've mentioned it twice already ;)). And as for changing published posts - yes, I know, I've added this condition, because published posts should not change their URLs - it will be bad for SEO.

Comment: I've tested it, - and what you said doesn't work. I can't get the ACF-field from the database from the `save_post`-filter, regardless of what I do. I've tested it extensively, - and I'm sure I'm right.

Comment: @Zeth, I don't know what you've tested, but priority is crucial thing if we talk about getting ACF fields during save_post. It is clearly stated in ACF docs, so you may say "I'm not right", but you're also saying then that ACF docs are incorrect and you know better. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/ (read all the page, there is explanation how to use priorities and what results you will get, and also that you can use WP save_post instead. And to be even more precise - the code in my answer is tested on clean WP install with clean ACF.

Comment: I'm not saying that I know better than the ACF docs. I'm saying that what you're saying is wrong - and you're mis-quoting the docs. You've linked to a page that proves _my_ point... That in order to access the ACF-fields, then you should adjust the priority on the `acf/save_post`-hook (less than 10 will do things to the ACF-field before it's saved, - and above 10 will do things to the ACF-field after it's saved). It doesn't say anything about the `save_post`. I'm not trying to pick a fight. And I'm gracious for your help. I'm just trying to help anyone else, who might come across the same prob

Comment: @Zeth `acf/save_post` is fired on `save_post` with priority 10. Just take a look at at line 43 in file `form-post.php`. You'll find this in there `add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_post'), 10, 2);` And in function `$this->save_post` there is call for function `acf_save_post( $post_id );` and in this function the hook `acf/save_post` is called. If you run your code using `save_post` with priority higher than 10, then it will run AFTER any `acf/save_post`. Sorry Zeth, you may think you've fond some magic knowledge, but you didn't - just read the docs and the code of that plugin. EOT.

Answer (score 0):

This may be oversimplifying what I'm reading but rather than using ACF fields to control the permalink, to modify the permalink in the URL the easiest thing to do would be to edit the permalink in the edit page of that particular post/page, rather than doing it programmatically.

If this is more complicated, you may want to look at the [WP_Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Rewrite) and create custom logic with that.

Also, you can [rewrite the permalink structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post#108647) in the CPT declaration

Comment: I don't think that saying to author "you have to do this manually" is a solution in here. Especially, that you can use ACF forms on front-end ;)

Comment: OP: "This is both a question on 'how to do this', as well as 'should I do this'." and I don't think going against the grain is a good idea. WP offers solutions for the problem built-in. So as good WP developers, we should strive to use them to make our solutions as robust as possible, within the context of the framework.

Comment: i totally agree. Just don't think that your answer is a solution - cause you suggest no solution other than "do it manually" ;) And this is answer for any question ("Can I automatically assign new posts to given category?" "Yes, do it manually", and so on). But I totally agree that you should use robust solutions using WP built-in api/functions and so on...

Comment: Fair enough. I'll leave this here anyway just in case it nudges the OP or another user on the right lines.