# Need help getting my Permalink structure right

Tags: permalinks

I have some problems setting up my permalink structure correctly. I am working with a custom post type and a custom taxonomy for this post type.

As of right now, my permalink structure that points to a single post from my custom post type looks like this:

```
domain.com/{Custom Post Type Slug}/{Single Post}
```

What I would like it to look like is:

```
domain.com/{Custom Post Type Slug}/{Taxonomy Term}/{Single Post}
```

Also, is it possible to point my Taxonomy Term Archives to a URL that looks like

```
domain.com/{CPT Slug}/{Taxonomy Term}
```

instead of

```
domain.com/{Taxonomy Slug}/{Taxonomy Term}?
```

I'm having some troubles finding the right approach to these problems. Wordpress offers some available tags for custom URL structure but they don't include my CPT or Taxonomy.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permalinks: custom post type -> custom taxonomy -> post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)