# Loop posts based on permalink term

Tags: wp-query, loop, permalinks, taxonomy, tax-query

I have setup my custom post's custom taxonomy's permalink structure to be:

**custom post type > custom taxonomy > post** (from [this helpful Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post))

Now I'm hoping to be able to code taxonomy.php to automatically loop posts based on the current permalink, ie: if the URL is **example.com/writing/fiction/** then the page (taxonomy.php) will show all posts with the taxonomy term "fiction" or if the URL is **example.com/writing/non-fiction** then taxonomy.php will show all posts with taxonomy term "non-fiction".

The goal is to only need 1 taxonomy.php file.

Here is current code (comment where I'm looking to make term automatic/dynamic):

```
    <?php 
        $posts = array (
            'post_type' => 'writing',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'type',
                    'terms' => 'fiction', // looking to automate this, based on URL
                ),
            ),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $posts );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <?php the_title('<h2>','</h2>');?>
            </a>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: is there a reason you're creating a new query in the template rather than using the default main query?

Comment: @milo sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? I'm needing to query the custom post type and this is how I've always done that :S

Comment: WordPress automatically generates the main query based on the requested URL. If you're viewing a taxonomy archive you don't have to create the query yourself, you just need to run the default loop like `while ( have_posts() ):` to output the contents of the main query.

Comment: Gonna sound stupid here, but, so...take out `$loop = new WP_Query( $posts );`?

Comment: Yes, and any reference to `$loop->`. If you look at the templates in any of the default themes that come with WordPress, they all contain this basic loop that just outputs main query. You only need to create your own query if you're outputting something separate and different from what would normally be viewed via that URL.

Comment: Okay, I'll go back and refresh my knowledge on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work with:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object () ;
```

and

```
'terms' => $queried_object->slug,
```

full code now:

```
    <?php
        $queried_object = get_queried_object () ;
        $posts = array (
            'post_type' => 'writing',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $queried_object->slug,
                ),
            ),
        );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $posts );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <?php the_title('<h2>','</h2>');?>
            </a>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you're after with:

```
'terms' => get_query_var( 'type' ),
```

Comment: Ah! Very nice. Not sure which method is better/faster/stronger but thank you for this option.