# Why is the term of my current page not returning a slug?

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, terms

Why is the term of my current page (custom taxonomy) not returning a slug? I have managed to get the following returned in my URL:

0, Array, '/{empty space}/

I am trying to pass the custom taxonomy term into my `$args` array object property `rewrite`. Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I have looked at many other posts on how to retrieve the current page custom taxonomy term and have already tried to implement the proposed solutions. Right now I'm at a total loss. The code below currently returns `/connect/series//destination_page`.

**How can I get the current page taxonomy term to appear in-between the two //?**

```
// Registers a new post type
add_action( 'init', 'message_init' );
function message_init() {

    // Get the queried object and sanitize it
    $current_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );

    // Get the page slug
    $slug = $current_page->post_name;

    $args = array(
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'connect/series/'. $slug),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies'         => array( 'category' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'message', $args );

}
```

Comment: Terms don't have a `post_name`, they're not posts, they have a `slug`. If you `var_dump( $current_page )`, you will see the contents of this object. However- I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, but I can tell you right now it's not going to work as you expect. Post types have to be registered *on every request*, and rewrite rules get cached between requests. Your post type is going to half-work on the current request, then disappear on the next page you visit.

Comment: @Milo, thank you for your response. I am trying to to rewrite the url for my custom taxonomy term page. I want the term to be included in the url when a user clicks a link that takes them to an article. Example: `https://www.example.com/connect/series/{term_name}/{post_name}/`. Right now all I can get is `https://www.example.com/connect/series/{post_name}/`. I am trying to dynamically capture the term name and insert it into the URL. Do you still think this is not possible?

Comment: I think maybe you're looking for something like [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post). The rewrite argument is a *pattern*, the pattern is used to generate the links for all posts. If you put a static slug in the rewrite argument, then all posts will have that one term in the permalink regardless of what terms it actually contains.