# How to approach a site where it has sub-businesses, each with its own pages ("articles", "staff")? Don't want to use WP multisite

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

The structure would be something like this.

> Main site
>
> - About Us
> - Our Staff
>
>   - Person A
>   - Person B, etc
> - Catering Service
>
>   - About Catering Service
>   - Staff of Catering
>
>     - Person 1
>     - Person 2, etc
>   - Articles of Catering
>
>     - Article 1, etc
> - Wedding Service
>
>   - About Wedding Service
>   - Staff of Wedding Service
>   - and so on...

What would be the best way to approach this kind of site?

I was thinking of making each subsites (catering, wedding, etc) as custom post types. The CPTs would be: "Main Site", "Catering Service", "Wedding Service", etc.

Then each CPT has their own taxonomy which would be: "About", "Staff", and "Articles". It would be then easy (there is [a solution in other question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)) to set the permalink to be something like:

> http://website.com/posttypes/taxonomy/post-title/
>
> (e.g.) http://website.com/catering/staff/person-1/

Initially it seems sound. However I'm not sure if this approach is the best solution. It's kinda hackish.

I prefer not using multisite.

Any tips or something that I should consider before moving forward?

Answer (score 1):

Logic suggests that:

- "Services" is taxonomy.
- "Catering" and "Wedding" are parent terms.
- "Staff" and "Articles" are child terms.
- "About Parent Term", "Person N" and "Article N" are either CPTs, posts or pages.
- "About Us", "Our Staff" and other accessories are the set of hierarchical pages or whatever.

Comment: This is great. However, what if the person overlaps? Say, Joe would appear both in /Catering/Staff/ and /Wedding/Staff. How would I make so if someone was brought to Joe's page from Catering, the design will show the Catering sub-business' design. Meanwhile, if someone was brought from Wedding, the design will show Wedding's design.

Comment: I meant to ask: how to show different design on one page (Joe) that depends on where did the user coming from?

Comment: Different design are about different templates and are off the scope of this question. Try to build a template and ask then.

Comment: I know how to build different templates. What I was trying to ask is, with your structure, how would one same page can have two different designs depending on where did the user coming from?

Comment: Okay, I end up opening a another question dealing with that exact question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332721/how-to-check-from-which-page-the-user-is-coming-to-the-current-page