# How to check from which page the user is coming to the current page?

Tags: php, functions, references

Is there a way of doing this with WordPress aside from using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Maybe something like a blend of `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `is_category()`. Something like,

```
came_from_category( 'uncategorized' )
```

or

```
came_from_home()
```

Comment: So you want to process the HTTP_REFERER to work out what page it was and test properties of it?

Comment: Or are you looking for an alternative mechanism? There isn't AFAIK any built-in user session where you could store their navigation path but you could add one.

Comment: I'm planning to have several pages that will display different color depends on where is the user coming from. Say, if the user comes from home, it would display the color blue (via attaching the `blue`class). If they come from other specific category, it would display the color green.

Comment: The simplest way may be to have those different pages generate a query string param on your page to indicate which color to use, and the you check for that query string in a plugin and write it to a cookie to remember for future pages.