# Custom post type url with category

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I register a custom post type, called `product` and also category called `cat_product`. now I want to set category name in slug for each post, current is:

```
'slug' => 'product',
'with_front' => false
),
```

I made this change:

```
'slug' => 'product/%cat_product%/',
'with_front' => false
),
```

But in front it show `%cat_product%` not category name! how can I fix this?

I want something like this:

```
mysite.com/product/category-name/product-name
```

but it shows:

```
mysite.com/product/%cat_product%/product-name
```

Comment: See [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post) about creating custom permalinks