# Custom post type / taxonomy rewrite archive page 2 gives 404

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives, 404-error, hierarchical

I've followed the code based off this and everything is working perfectly -[How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types)

So I am able to browse taxonomy archives with

```
my/category
(or)
my/category/subcategory
```

and view a custom post associated with each term as

```
my/category/subcategory/custompost
```

However, I cannot view

```
my/category/page/2/
or
my/category/subcategory/page/2/
```

It gives me a 404.

Here is the code I am using.

### posttype.my.php

```
function create_my_posttype() {
    register_post_type(
        'my',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Mys', 'post type general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'My', 'post type singular name' ),
            'add_new' => _x( 'New My', 'add new singular name' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New My' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit My' ),
            'new_item' => __( 'New My' ),
            'view_item' => __( 'View My' ),
            'search_items' => __( 'Search Mys' ),
            'not_found' =>  __( 'No Mys Found' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Mys found in Trash' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => '-:-'
         ),

        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'my/%mycategory%',
            'with_front' => true,
            'pages' => true
        ),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
        'menu_position' => 50,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'comments',
            'shortlink'
        ),
    )
);
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_my_posttype');
```

### taxonomy.my.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_taxonomies', 0 );

function create_my_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
            'mycategory',
            'my',
            array(
                    'labels' => array(
                            'name' => 'Mycategories',
            'singular_name' => 'Mycategory',
            'search_items' => 'Search Mycategories',
            'all_items' => 'All Mycategories',
            'parent_item' => 'Parent Mycategories',
                            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Mycategory',
                            'new_item_name' => "New Mycategory",
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Mycategory',
            'update_item' => 'Update Mycategory',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Mycategory',
            'new_item_name' => 'New MyCategory Name',
            'menu_name' => 'Mycategory'
                    ),

        'query_var' => true,
                    'show_ui' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
                    'show_tagcloud' => false,
                    'hierarchical' => true,
                    'with_front' => true,
                    'rewrite' => array(
                            'slug' => 'my',
                            'with_front' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
                    )
            )
    );
}
```

### main.php

```
include( 'posttype.my.php' );
include( 'taxonomy.my.php' );


add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
$newRules  = array();
$newRules['my/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?my=$matches[3]';
$newRules['my/(.+)/?$']                = 'index.php?mycategory=$matches[1]';

return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
if ($post->post_type != 'my')
    return $link;

if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'mycategory'))
{
    $link = str_replace('%mycategory%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'mycategory', false, '/', true), $link); // see custom function defined below
}
return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);


function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {
$chain = '';
$parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
    return $parent;
}

if ($nicename)
    $name = $parent -> slug;
else
    $name = $parent -> name;

if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {
    $visited[] = $parent -> parent;
    $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

}

if ($link) {
    // nothing, can't get this working :(
} else
    $chain .= $name . $separator;
return $chain;
}

class main_app {
    function __construct() {
    } // end class main_app


}
```

If anyone can help or point me in the right direction that'd be amazing. I don't want to resort to separate URL slugs for taxonomies and custom post types :\ Do I have to modify the rewrite rule to include something involving "paged" ?

Thanks

Comment: I know that if I rename my category to 'mys' it's ok, but that's not really what I'm going for.. So it's a slug conflict error but it only conflicts on page2, so I need to add more code in the app.php to recognise the page/2....

Comment: according to your rewrite rules, `my/category/page/2/` will try to load a `my` post named `2`, so yes, you need additional rewrite rules to handle URLs containing `page`. try using [this rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) to give you a look at how your URLs are being parsed.

Comment: Whay! That rewrite analyzer plugin was really helpful :) I added another rewrite rule as the first rule above the other two.. `$newRules['my/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$']           =  'index.php?mycategory=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';` Seems to have done the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe echoing the last query will help debug the problem.
Paste this on your 404 page:

```
global $wpdb;
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($wpdb->last_query);
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem with pagination for WordPress custom post types a few months ago. What really helped me was [this article](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-post-type-pagination-chaining-method--wp-21444) on Tuts+. The basic idea is to chain your custom page template (page-my.php) to the archive page template (archive-my.php). This enables pagination for Custom Posttypes, together with a small custom pagination function.

After following the steps in the article I no longer got the dreaded 404 when navigating to page 2 and beyond.

You can see a working example [here](http://www.radiomerlijn.nl/radiogids/page/2/)