# How to get list of taxonomy slugs ordered parents>childs?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, taxonomy, rewrite-rules

Is there an existing function in WordPress to generate a list of taxonomy slugs ordered by `parents > childs > subchilds` in an array? I need to generate a URL structure for my custom post type in the format `example.com/parents/childs/subchilds/postname`.

I see the default post type in WordPress already does this but my custom post type is of "page" type.

So far I'm doing this:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'scategory');   // scategory is my custom taxonomy     
$slugs = [];
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $slugs[$term->term_id] = $term->slug;
}
ksort($slugs); // sorting by slug ids
$finalSlug = join( '/', $slugs ); // making rewrite rule slug for custom post type
```

By default, `get_the_terms` outputs terms in alphabetical order; that's why I sorted it by their keys, so that I can assume the terms with lower IDs as parents and others as children, but this isn't reliable in the long run.

Comment: I couldn't get to work this function either http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39862/64925