# How to check if last uri segment is a custom post type or taxonomy term?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules, hierarchical

After following Jeffs suggestion on [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) to create nested parent and child taxonomy terms within a permalink like...

url.com/custom-post-type/taxonomy-parent/taxonomy-child/cpt-entry

It mostly works except for one problem.

Before I continue, I should mention I have a custom post type called **gallery** and a taxonomy called **gallery_cat**.

WORKING

```
/gallery/ - archive-gallery.php
/gallery/wedding-cakes/ - parent taxonomy - taxonomy-gallery_cat.php     
/gallery/wedding-cakes/chocolate/ - child taxonomy - taxonomy-gallery_cat.php      
/gallery/wedding-cakes/chocolate/cpt-entry/ - CPT entry under child taxonomy - single-gallery.php
```

NOT WORKING

`/gallery/wedding-cakes/cpt-entry/ - CPT entry under parent taxonomy`

Here is my code in functions.php:

```
// ADD A GALLERY CUSTOM POST TYPE WITH GALLERY_CAT TAXONOMY
add_action('init', 'create_gallery_post_type');

function create_gallery_post_type() {

register_taxonomy(
    'gallery_cat',
    'gallery',
     array(
        'label' => 'Categories',
        'singular_label' => 'Category',
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'gallery', 'hierarchical' => true ),
    )
);

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Photo', 'post type singular name'),
'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'gallery'),
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'author', 'comments'),
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'gallery/%gallery_cat%',
        'with_front' => false
    ),
    'has_archive' => 'gallery',
    'menu_icon' => get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/images/gallery-icon.png' //16x16 png if you want an icon
); 

register_post_type( 'gallery' , $args );
}



function filter_post_type_link($link, $post) {
if ($post->post_type != 'gallery')
    return $link;
if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'gallery_cat')) {
    $link = str_replace('%gallery_cat%', rtrim(get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'gallery_cat', false, '/', true),"/"), $link); // see custom function defined below
}
return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);


// my own function to do what get_category_parents does for other taxonomies
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {    
$chain = '';   
$parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
    return $parent;
}

if ($nicename)    
    $name = $parent -> slug;        
else    
    $name = $parent -> name;

if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {    
    $visited[] = $parent -> parent;    
    $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);
}
if ($link) {
    // nothing, can't get this working :(
} else    
    $chain .= $name . $separator;
return $chain;    
}


//Rewrite rules
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'gallery_rewrite_rules');
function gallery_rewrite_rules($rules) {
$newRules  = array();

$newRules['gallery/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?gallery=$matches[3]';   
$newRules['gallery/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?gallery_cat=$matches[2]'; 
$newRules['gallery/(.+)/?$']      = 'index.php?gallery_cat=$matches[1]';

return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

Now, I think the problem is where I need to add the following line to the rewrite rules array:

`$newRules['gallery/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?gallery=$matches[2]';`

because my custom structure won't always have the post name as the 3rd uri segment because if the CPT is only under a parent taxonomy, than it will be in the 2nd uri segment.

But when I add that, it breaks things. My best guess is that it is clashing with this line...

`$newRules['gallery/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?gallery_cat=$matches[2]';`

Jeff, who helped me make it this far from [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types), said the following...

> If you'll have varying levels of nested terms then you'll need to
>   write a function to check whether the the last uri segment is a custom
>   post type or a taxonomy term to know which rule to add

Anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see how we can make this work, have a read through the [Query Overview Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Query_Overview), particularly the **What Plugins can Modify** section:

> Modify the query specification, after variable values are saved (`request` filter or `parse_request` action; if you want to use conditional tag tests, use the `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts` action, as these run after the `is_` variables are set).

In this case, we want to filter `request`, which will be an array of the query vars which were set by the [`parse_request` method of the `WP` class](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src//wp-includes/class-wp.php#L110) (scroll to the end of this function to see where the filter is applied).

In our filter, we'll check if `gallery_cat` is set, and if the requested term is actually an existing `gallery_cat` term. If it's not, we'll assume it's a `gallery` post, and reset the query vars to make WordPress query for the post instead of the term. To do that we need to set 3 different query vars- `gallery`, `name`, and `post_type`.

```
function wpd_gallery_request_filter( $request ){
    if( array_key_exists( 'gallery_cat' , $request )
        && ! get_term_by( 'slug', $request['gallery_cat'], 'gallery_cat' ) ){
            $request['gallery'] = $request['gallery_cat'];
            $request['name'] = $request['gallery_cat'];
            $request['post_type'] = 'gallery';
            unset( $request['gallery_cat'] );
    }
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpd_gallery_request_filter' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Milo, can you please tell me where and how I would use this function exactly?

Comment: it would go in your `functions.php` file with the rest of your code, just paste it in there and it'll do its thing.

Comment: How that worked goes completely over my head (even though you explained it very well) but yes it worked. Had to flush the permalinks. Thanks Milo

Comment: I am having another problem that is related to the above question. 

The main archive page of my gallery is at url.com/gallery
Now when the pagination occurs, it becomes /gallery/page/2.

But this clashes with the rewrite_rules_array filter function causing a 404 page not found. What can I add to the rewrite_rules_array to solve this?

Comment: you have to add another rule with `/page/` and set the `paged` query var. if you `var_dump` the contents of `$rules` inside your filter, you'll see the pagination rules WordPress generates for other archives and you can copy that format.