# WordPress Rewrite Rule to EITHER Match 1 or 2 Taxonomies when adding to URL

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type `residential` using a custom taxonomy `residential_taxonomies` and I am adding the taxonomy term(s) and the post type name to the url.

It works fine if there are always a parent & child taxonomy term making the url like `/residential/tax-1/tax-2/post-slug`, but I don't know how to update my matching `RegExp` to match either 1 or 2 taxonomy terms and be either `/residential/tax-1/tax-2/post-slug` or `/residential/tax-1/post-slug` if only one taxonomy is selected.

I know how to do either or but not both.

My current code is as follows:

```
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');

function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();

    $newRules['residential/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?residential=$matches[3]';
    $newRules['residential/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?residential_taxonomies=$matches[2]';

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}
```

Comment: If something might be either a tax term or a post slug, there's no way to resolve that with just regex, you have to [do something like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177015/4771) to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: That solution worked perfectly. I don't quite understand it at this point. Will need to dig into more. Thank you