# Insert post ID into the end of a slug preceeded by a dash

Tags: url-rewriting, id

I would like to dynamically insert post IDs into their URL slugs.

**What I have**

- Code that strips out the prepended post name (WC's '/product')
- Code that generates the URL that I want

**What I want**

- URLs that look like: `~/category-name/hey-slug-12903/`
- The reason for this is I have loads of products that are only different because of the category within which they reside...as such I want to automatically insert the ID *within the subdirectory* to prevent any duplicate weirdness.
- I **do not want** IDs to be appended as superfluous subdirectories like: `~/category-name/hey-slug/12903/` or `~/category-name/12903/hey-slug/`

**My Issue**

- I'm getting 404s (I've flushed rewrite rules)
- I don't know if I also need to use `add_rewrite_rule();`

**My Code:**

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpp_remove_slug', 10, 3 );
function wpp_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $name ) {

    if ( 'product' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
      return $post_link;
    }
    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
    $post_link = substr($post_link, 0, -1);
    $post_link = $post_link . "-" . $post->ID . '/';
    return $post_link;


}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `%post_id%` and `%product_cat%` tags in the custom base for the permalink product settings?

Comment: Yes, I have tried `/%product_cat%/%post_id%-` in permalink settings, but WP always appends a `/` ..when I try to remove the slash and make the ID separated by a dash, I get a 404 again.

Answer (score 2):

The `rewrite` argument in `register_post_type` is limited, but you can define a more complex structure with `add_permastruct`. The added benefits are that this will generate all the rewrite rules for you, and the new rules will overwrite the originals. You just have to be sure to hook after the post type is registered.

```
function wpd_woo_product_permastruct(){
    add_permastruct(
        'product',
        '%product_cat%/%product%-%post_id%/',
        array(
            'walk_dirs' => false,
            'with_front' => false
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_woo_product_permastruct', 99 );
```

And that is, magically, all you need. The rewrite tag replacements will be done for you, so the `post_type_link` filter won't be needed.

Normally, the absence of a static slug would cause clashes with other rules, but in this case it works because the embedded post ID triggers a more strict match.

What you *can't* have is the `%product_cat%` rules without a static slug, which is why we have to set `walk_dirs` to `false`. Otherwise, any request for a root page will be overridden by the taxonomy rule, and WordPress will go looking for a term that matches your page slug.

If you *do* want rules that introduce this ambiguity, you can do something like [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177015/4771), where you manually resolve conflicts.

Comment: Much simpler +1 :)

Comment: I have a question, i tried this with products using the same slug and WP still appended the -2 (i.e. ~?/cat-1/my-post-12345, ~?/cat-2/my-post-2-12345) is there any way to disable appending the -2?

Comment: hmm, might need to rethink the approach. `wp_unique_post_slug` will still enforce unique slugs, this is separate from permalink structure. there's a filter of the same name that you can use to manually override it. but then why not just skip adding post ID onto the end and use the unique slugs wp generates?

Comment: hello @Milo  can you check please, this question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/376279/when-i-modify-the-products-permalink-the-pages-stop-working  I've done something similar, but the post types stop working.That is to say, all the rules I have set work, but the others do not.