# How can I add a "fake" parent into the permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, hierarchical

I have a custom post type of `books` and a taxonomy of `book-publishers-series`. I am trying to do a rewrite so that my urls look like:

```
domain/publishing/books/book-publishers-series-parent/book-publishers-series-child/book
```

Here is the code for my CPT and taxonomy:

```
$labels = array(
    "name" => "Books",
    "singular_name" => "Book",
    "menu_name" => "Books",
    "all_items" => "All Books",
    "add_new" => "Add New",
    "add_new_item" => "Add New Book",
    "edit" => "Edit",
    "edit_item" => "Edit Book",
    "new_item" => "New Book",
    "view" => "View",
    "view_item" => "View Book",
    "search_items" => "Search Books",
    "not_found" => "No Books Found",
    "not_found_in_trash" => "No Books Found in Trash",
    "parent" => "Parent Book",
    );

$args = array(
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "has_archive" => true,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => false,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "publishing/books/%book-publishers-series%", "with_front" => true ),
    "query_var" => true,
    "supports" => array( "title", "revisions", "thumbnail" ),
    "taxonomies" => array( "book-publishers-series", "series" ) );
register_post_type( "books", $args );

$labels = array(
    "name" => "book-publishers-series",
    "label" => "Book Publishers/Series",
    "menu_name" => "Book Publishers/Series",
    "all_items" => "All Book Publishers/Series",
    "edit_item" => "Edit Book Publisher/Series",
    "view_item" => "View Book Publisher/Series",
    "update_item" => "Update Book Publisher/Series",
    "add_new_item" => "Add New Book Publisher/Series",
    "new_item_name" => "New Book Publisher/Series",
    "parent_item" => "Parent Book Type/Genre",
    "parent_item_colon" => "Parent Book Type/Genre:",
    "search_items" => "Search Book Publishers/Series",
    "popular_items" => "Popular Book Publishers/Series",
    "add_or_remove_items" => "Add or Remove Book Publishers/Series",
    "not_found" => "No Book Publishers/Series",
        );

$args = array(
    "labels" => $labels,
    "hierarchical" => true,
    "label" => "Book Publishers/Series",
    "show_ui" => true,
    "query_var" => true,
    "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'publishing/books', 'with_front' => true true),
    "show_admin_column" => false,
);
register_taxonomy( "book-publishers-series", array( "books" ), $args );
```

I have a couple of functions in functions.php to replace `%book-publishers-series%` with the taxonomy levels (it is hierarchical).

```
function rewrite_add_taxonomy( $link, $taxonomy, $default ) {
    // Get post
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    if (!$post) return $permalink;

    // Get taxonomy terms
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, $taxonomy);   
    if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) {
        $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        if ($terms[0]->parent) {
            $parent_term = get_term($terms[0]->parent, $taxonomy);
            $taxonomy_slug = $parent_term->slug.'/'.$taxonomy_slug;
        }
    } else {
        $taxonomy_slug = $default;
    } 

    return str_replace('%'.$taxonomy.'%', $taxonomy_slug, $link);
}

function append_query_string( $link, $post ) {

    if ( 'books' == get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        return rewrite_add_taxonomy( $link, 'book-publishers-series', 'no-category' );
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

The archive for books at `domain/publishing/books` works fine, but loading an actual book gives me a 404. The url looks accurate, but obviously I have done something wrong because WP doesn't understand it. So, there must be something wrong with the `rewrite_add_taxonomy()` function. I tried to adapt it to work with a hierarchical taxonomy with parents and children. It works fine for hierarchical taxonomies without parents/children.

HOWEVER, if I remove "publishing" from the books CPT rewrite, I can view a book without any problem, even with the `rewrite_add_taxonomy()` function the way it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Somewhat like this »[How to create a permalink structure with custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/39500/22534)«?

Comment: I had actually seen that post before and didn't get any better results doing it that way. I see I had forgotten to include the rewrite rule he had first to get "basename" in there. I did that. Now viewing a book works, but viewing the books archive at `publishing/books` gives me a 404. I swear, rewrites are maddening.

Comment: Spoke too soon...now neither works. *sigh*

Comment: I've copied his code verbatim now and it does not work for viewing the post. I can view the stages in-between, like the archive pages for the post type and the categories, but not the post.

Comment: install [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and have a look at how rules are matched. the rewrite parameter in your post type registration only covers a single level of term before the post name. you need extra rules to cover additional levels of terms

Comment: I started reading some tutorials online last night. I think rewrites are as hard to learn as all the rest of WordPress! :-D I've always sucked at regex, so that's one massive hurdle to getting it figured out. There are still 1000 things about rewrites I don't understand yet. But then, I've only been working with WordPress for 3 weeks. :-)

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to understand how the rewrite rules work. One question so far: If I have something like this: `add_rewrite_rule( '^publishing/books/(.+)/(.+)/?$','index.php?books=$matches[2]','top' );` I get that the matches[2] targets the second set of parentheses and that's where it's looking for the book name. I'd need to make the matches[1] the taxonomy. But, what if you don't know how many levels the taxonomy stretches out? If it's one level, that's easy. But, if it's two or three, how do you know that matches[2] will be the correct location for the book name?