# Wordpress permalink setting

Tags: plugin-development, functions, theme-development, permalinks, filters

I have a doubt.

If book is my custom post type, language is my taxonomy, english is the item in taxonomy , Harrypotter is new post in book with txonomy english.
Then how i get the url structure like

(1)  www.example.com/books/language/english/harrypotter
(2)  www.example.com/books/english/harrypotter

If novel is sub taxonomy under english then

(3)  www.example.com/books/language/english/novel/harrypotter
(4)  www.example.com/books/english/novel/harrypotter

I read many examples like [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types/39862#39862)  and [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/),  but i can't figer out how to do this .

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the permalink structure, it can be done in admin panel.

Go setting -> permalinks and chose what you need in general settings